# Get the real width and height of an image with JavaScript? (in Safari/Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, google-chrome, webkit

I am creating a jQuery plugin.

How do I get the real image width and height with Javascript in Safari?

The following works with Firefox 3, IE7 and Opera 9:

```
var pic = $("img")

// need to remove these in of case img-element has set width and height
pic.removeAttr("width"); 
pic.removeAttr("height");

var pic_real_width = pic.width();
var pic_real_height = pic.height();
```

But in Webkit browsers like Safari and Google Chrome values are 0.

Comment: The accepted answer uses the image load event. Makes perfect sense, but turns out to be an unreliable solution in situations where images can be cached (much to my dismay).

Comment: My take on this may help you, tested in latest Webkit. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome/7573016#7573016

Comment: @Nosredna, you may be interested in the [imagesLoaded](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) function that will fire even when images have been cached.

Comment: The correct answer to this question is to simply use the naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties. No hackery required.

Comment: You could also do exactly what you're doing on window load instead of document ready

Comment: img.naturalWidth and img.naturalHeight is correct answer

Answer (score 355, accepted):

Webkit browsers set the height and width property after the image is loaded.  Instead of using timeouts, I'd recommend using an image's onload event.  Here's a quick example:

```
var img = $("img")[0]; // Get my img elem
var pic_real_width, pic_real_height;
$("<img/>") // Make in memory copy of image to avoid css issues
    .attr("src", $(img).attr("src"))
    .load(function() {
        pic_real_width = this.width;   // Note: $(this).width() will not
        pic_real_height = this.height; // work for in memory images.
    });
```

To avoid any of the effects CSS might have on the image's dimensions, the code above makes an in memory copy of the image.  This is a very clever solution suggested by [FDisk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630#3192577).

You can also use the `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` HTML5 attributes.

Comment: I'm testing on Firefox 3 and $(document).ready() also doesn't work as well.

Comment: On some browsers, load does not fire on a cached image (which makes me sad). Opera, for one. But Opera returns to correct width and height immediately, so you can work around that. Unfortunately, the latest Chrome on my machine seems to suffer from the same problem, so I'd say this solution is unreliable.

Comment: You're entirely correct Nosredna. I completely overlooked that case. In the past I've gotten around this bug/feature by executing `img.src = img.src` after I attached the img's onload event. I'll update my answer to handle this case.

Comment: I recently learned that the `img.src = img.src` doesn't works in Chrome 3.0.  That said, I believe I may have found a work around: set the image source to empty string then back to the original source. I'll update my answer.

Comment: In addition to `width` and `height` you should probably also remove `min-width`, `min-height`, `max-width` and `max-height` as they could also influence the image dimensions.

Comment: I suggest reading FDisk's answer before adopting this convoluted approach. (I realize that this question is several months old, but I've added this comment for the benefit of future visitors.)

Comment: FDisk's solution is a very clever.  Unfortunately the solution as he has written it will only work if the image is cached or if the page has already finished downloading.  If the image is not cached or if this code is called before `window.onload`, a height/width of 0 might be returned.  In any case, I've integrated FDisk's idea into the solution above.

Comment: You could also use the HTML5 attributes naturalHeight and naturalWidth.

Comment: when i try to console.log(pic_real_height) i get undefined every time. chrome, FF, IE9.

Comment: The problem you may have here is that `load()` will be executed asynchronously so if you want to access `width` and `height` — they may not been set yet. Instead do “the magic“ in the `load()` itself!

Comment: how can we turn these true values to a gloab variable ?

Comment: This is a great solution and worked for the most part but IE will cause problems if you handle more then one image. If you want to fix then then add a random parameter to the image url so IE fires the load function properly. `+"?"+new Date().getTime()` Got that from here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/fixing-load-in-ie-for-cached-images/

Comment: if use .load() i can't update parent variable, how to do that?

Comment: @TomSawyer I'm sorry, I don't understand.  You can update any variable from within the function you pass into `.load`.  Though keep in mind the `.load` is asynchronous, so all the code that uses the height and width _needs_ to be called from the function passed into `.load`.

Comment: From experience I can tell you that it's important to always set your load event BEFORE you set the src. Otherwise mysterious bugs may show up.

Comment: For jQuery 3.0+ use `.on("load", function(){ ... })` instead of `.load(...)`.

Answer (score 289):

Use the `naturalHeight` and `naturalWidth` attributes from [HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element).

For example:

```
var h = document.querySelector('img').naturalHeight;
```

*Works in IE9+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera ([stats](http://caniuse.com/#feat=img-naturalwidth-naturalheight)).*

Comment: @DavidJohnstone An example of them being used might help. But I agree, definitely deserves to be higher up.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in the latest version of FireFox (30.0) unless the image already exists in the cache.

Comment: Note that you still need to wait for the image to load

Comment: No, clientHeight/clientWidth explicitly don't do what the question asks. It needs to return the height and width of the image, not the height and width of the image as it looks on the page. naturalWidth and naturalHeight are correct.

Answer (score 62):

```
function getOriginalWidthOfImg(img_element) {
    var t = new Image();
    t.src = (img_element.getAttribute ? img_element.getAttribute("src") : false) || img_element.src;
    return t.width;
}
```

You don't need to remove style from the image or image dimensions attributes. Just create an element with javascript and get the created object width.

Comment: Since a few months, cloning an image with jquery (using the latest Chrome) and getting it's properties, always returns 0x0

So far this is the only solutions that works (have tested all the others in this page)
Before returning, I set t=null too.

Comment: FDisk is not suggesting cloning the image with jQuery. He's suggesting creating a new `Image` object, then looking at its `width` property. This is a simple, elegant approach. FDisk, you have my vote. :)

Comment: This is a very clever way to avoid css issues.  Unfortunately the solution as written above will only work if the image is cached or has already finished downloading.  If the image is not cached or if this code is called before `window.onload`, a width of 0 might be returned.

Comment: I'm using this approach in a website for the mobile phones in image gallery. Bigger images then the resolution is displayed with with 100% in css and smaller in original dimensions.

Comment: As Xavi mentioned, this fails in IE8 and sometimes depending on image caching. So I coupled it with this approach, and it works perfect: bind the load event first, then assign the image object its source http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4921712/load-event-with-jquery-fails-in-ie-8

Comment: What exactly should you pass in to this function?

Answer (score 17):

There's a lot of discussion in the accepted answer about a problem where the `onload` event doesn't fire if an image is loaded from the WebKit cache.

In my case, `onload` fires for cached images, but the height and width are still 0.  A simple `setTimeout` resolved the issue for me:

```
$("img").one("load", function(){
    var img = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
        // do something based on img.width and/or img.height
    }, 0);
});
```

I can't speak as to why the `onload` event is firing even when the image is loaded from the cache (improvement of jQuery 1.4/1.5?) — but if you are still experiencing this problem, maybe a combination of my answer and the `var src = img.src; img.src = ""; img.src = src;` technique will work.

(Note that for my purposes, I'm not concerned about pre-defined dimensions, either in the image's attributes or CSS styles — but you might want to remove those, as per Xavi's answer.  Or clone the image.)

Comment: I had this very problem with IE7 & IE8. 

setTimeout() worked for me for those browsers.

Thank you!

Answer (score 15):

The root problem is that WebKit browsers (Safari and Chrome) load JavaScript and CSS information in parallel. Thus, JavaScript may execute before the styling effects of CSS have been computed, returning the wrong answer. In jQuery, I've found that the solution is to wait until document.readyState == 'complete', .e.g.,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  if (jQuery.browser.safari && document.readyState != "complete"){
    //console.info('ready...');
    setTimeout( arguments.callee, 100 );
    return;
  } 
  ... (rest of function)
```

As far as width and height goes... depending on what you are doing you may want offsetWidth and offsetHeight, which include things like borders and padding.

Comment: Yeah, that's the reason. A better workaround is to use jQuery's load-event.

Comment: `$(window).load(function(){ ... });` helped in my case

Answer (score 11):

this works for me (safari 3.2), by firing from within the `window.onload` event:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var pic = $('img');

  pic.removeAttr("width"); 
  pic.removeAttr("height");

  alert( pic.width() );
  alert( pic.height() );
});
```

Comment: Yeah! Didn't work from $(document).ready(function(){});
Thanks! It needs to have the image fully loaded before it can read it. Ofcourse.

Answer (score 8):

You can programmatically get the image and check the dimensions using Javascript without having to mess with the DOM at all.

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  console.log(this.width + 'x' + this.height);
}
img.src = 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif';
```

Comment: This is the best solution! It works even if the image is not pre-loaded or cached.

Answer (score 7):

What about `image.naturalHeight` and `image.naturalWidth` properties?

Seems to work fine back quite a few versions in Chrome, Safari and Firefox, but not at all in IE8 or even IE9.

Comment: this is not working in my case. giving me NaN in return

Answer (score 6):

Jquery has two properties called naturalWidth and naturalHeight, you can use in this way.

```
$('.my-img')[0].naturalWidth 
$('.my-img')[0].naturalHeight
```

Where my-img is a class name used to select my image.

Comment: These aren't jQuery methods. `naturalWidth` (and height) are properties on the image element object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement

Answer (score 5):

How we get right real dimensions without a blink real image:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.getDimensions=function(){
         alert("First example:This works only for HTML code without CSS width/height definition.");
         w=$(this, 'img')[0].width;
         h=$(this, 'img')[0].height;

         alert("This is a width/height on your monitor: " + $(this, 'img')[0].width+"/"+$(this, 'img')[0].height);

         //This is bad practice - it shows on your monitor
         $(this, 'img')[0].removeAttribute( "width" );
         $(this, 'img')[0].removeAttribute( "height" );
         alert("This is a bad effect of view after attributes removing, but we get right dimensions: "+  $(this, 'img')[0].width+"/"+$(this, 'img')[0].height);
         //I'am going to repare it
         $(this, 'img')[0].width=w;
         $(this, 'img')[0].height=h;
         //This is a good practice - it doesn't show on your monitor
         ku=$(this, 'img').clone(); //We will work with a clone
         ku.attr( "id","mnbv1lk87jhy0utrd" );//Markup clone for a final removing
         ku[0].removeAttribute( "width" );
         ku[0].removeAttribute( "height" );
         //Now we still get 0
         alert("There are still 0 before a clone appending to document: "+ $(ku)[0].width+"/"+$(ku)[0].height);
         //Hide a clone
         ku.css({"visibility" : "hidden",'position':'absolute','left':'-9999px'}); 
         //A clone appending
         $(document.body).append (ku[0]);
         alert("We get right dimensions: "+ $(ku)[0].width+"/"+$(ku)[0].height);
         //Remove a clone
         $("#mnbv1lk87jhy0utrd").remove();

         //But a next resolution is the best of all. It works in case of CSS definition of dimensions as well.
         alert("But if you want to read real dimensions for image with CSS class definition outside of img element, you can't do it with a clone of image. Clone method is working with CSS dimensions, a clone has dimensions as well as in CSS class. That's why you have to work with a new img element.");
         imgcopy=$('<img src="'+ $(this, 'img').attr('src') +'" />');//new object 
         imgcopy.attr( "id","mnbv1lk87jhy0aaa" );//Markup for a final removing
         imgcopy.css({"visibility" : "hidden",'position':'absolute','left':'-9999px'});//hide copy 
         $(document.body).append (imgcopy);//append to document 
         alert("We get right dimensions: "+ imgcopy.width()+"/"+imgcopy.height());
         $("#mnbv1lk87jhy0aaa").remove();


   }
})( jQuery );

$(document).ready(function(){

   $("img.toreaddimensions").click(function(){$(this).getDimensions();});
});
```

It works with <img class="toreaddimensions"...

Answer (score 3):

As stated before, [Xavi answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318630/get-real-image-width-and-height-with-javascript-in-safari-chrome/670433#670433) won't work if images are in the cache. The issue responds to webkit not firing the load event on cached images, so if the width/height attrs are no explicitly set in the img tag, the only reliable way to get the images is to wait for the `window.load` event to be fired.

The `window.load` event will fire **always**, so it's safe to access the width/height of and img after that without any trick.

```
$(window).load(function(){

   //these all work

   $('img#someId').css('width');
   $('img#someId').width();
   $('img#someId').get(0).style.width;
   $('img#someId').get(0).width; 

});
```

If you need to get the size of dynamically loaded images that might get cached (previously loaded), you can use Xavi method plus a query string to trigger a cache refresh. The downside is that it will cause another request to the server, for an img that is already cached and should be already available. Stupid Webkit.

```
var pic_real_width   = 0,
    img_src_no_cache = $('img#someId').attr('src') + '?cache=' + Date.now();

$('<img/>').attr('src', img_src_no_cache).load(function(){

   pic_real_width = this.width;

});
```

ps: if you have a QueryString in the `img.src` already, you will have to [parse it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript) and add the extra param to clear the cache.

Comment: First block of code just gets the dimensions of an element in loaded DOM, not of an image itself...

Comment: This is exactly the Fastest & Most Effective solution. No plugin, no trick! I'm going to post a similar answer but found yours.

Answer (score 2):

As Luke Smith says, [image load is a mess](http://twitter.com/ls_n/status/5178745627). It's not reliable on all browsers. This fact has given me great pain. A cached image will not fire the event at all in some browsers, so those who said "image load is better than setTimeout" are wrong.

Luke Smith's solution is [here.](http://lucassmith.name/2008/11/is-my-image-loaded.html)

And there is [an interesting discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/jquery-dev/browse_frm/thread/eee6ab7b2da50e1f) about how this mess might be handled in jQuery 1.4.

I have found that it's pretty reliable to set the width to 0, then wait for the "complete" property to go true and the width property to come in greater than zero. You should watch for errors, too.

Comment: Second link in answer is dead.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#myImg").one("load",function(){
  //do something, like getting image width/height
}).each(function(){
  if(this.complete) $(this).trigger("load");
});
```

From Chris' comment: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

Answer (score 2):

My situation is probably a little different. I am dynamically changing the src of an image via javascript and needed to ensure that the new image is sized proportionally to fit a fixed container (in a photo gallery). I initially just removed the width and height attributes of the image after it is loaded (via the image's load event) and reset these after calculating the preferred dimensions. However, that does not work in Safari and possibly IE (I have not tested it in IE thoroughly, but the image doesn't even show, so...).

Anyway, Safari keeps the dimensions of the previous image so the dimensions are always one image behind. I assume that this has something to do with cache. So the simplest solution is to just clone the image and add it to the DOM (it is important that it be added to the DOM the get the with and height). Give the image a visibility value of hidden (do not use display none because it will not work). After you get the dimensions remove the clone.

Here is my code using jQuery:

```
// Hack for Safari and others
// clone the image and add it to the DOM
// to get the actual width and height
// of the newly loaded image

var cloned, 
    o_width, 
    o_height, 
    src = 'my_image.jpg', 
    img = [some existing image object];

$(img)
.load(function()
{
    $(this).removeAttr('height').removeAttr('width');
    cloned = $(this).clone().css({visibility:'hidden'});
    $('body').append(cloned);
    o_width = cloned.get(0).width; // I prefer to use native javascript for this
    o_height = cloned.get(0).height; // I prefer to use native javascript for this
    cloned.remove();
    $(this).attr({width:o_width, height:o_height});
})
.attr(src:src);
```

This solution works in any case.

Answer (score 1):

There is now a jQuery plugin, `event.special.load`, to deal with cases where the load event on a cached image doesn't fire: http://github.com/peol/jquery.imgloaded/raw/master/ahpi.imgload.js

Answer (score 1):

Recently I needed to find width and height for setting default size of .dialog representing graph. Solution I use was :

```
 graph= $('<img/>', {"src":'mySRC', id:'graph-img'});
    graph.bind('load', function (){
        wid = graph.attr('width');
        hei = graph.attr('height');

        graph.dialog({ autoOpen: false, title: 'MyGraphTitle', height:hei, width:wid })
    })
```

For me this works in FF3, Opera 10, IE 8,7,6

P.S. You may be find some more solutions looking inside some plugins like LightBox or ColorBox

Answer (score 1):

To add to Xavi's answer, <strike>[Paul Irish's github](https://gist.github.com/268257)</strike> [David Desandro's gitgub offers a function called imagesLoaded()](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) that works on the same principles, and gets around the problem of some browser's cached images not firing the .load() event (with clever original_src -> data_uri -> original_src switching).

It's is widely used and updated regularly, which contributes to it being the most robust solution to the problem, IMO.

Comment: You can find an updated version of the `imagesLoaded` function here: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

Comment: Yep, David Desandro is hosting the function now. Thanks for reminding me @somethingkindawierd, updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works for both cached and dynamically loaded images.

```
function LoadImage(imgSrc, callback){
  var image = new Image();
  image.src = imgSrc;
  if (image.complete) {
    callback(image);
    image.onload=function(){};
  } else {
    image.onload = function() {
      callback(image);
      // clear onLoad, IE behaves erratically with animated gifs otherwise
      image.onload=function(){};
    }
    image.onerror = function() {
        alert("Could not load image.");
    }
  }
}
```

To use this script:

```
function AlertImageSize(image) {
  alert("Image size: " + image.width + "x" + image.height);
}
LoadImage("http://example.org/image.png", AlertImageSize);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9543z/2/

Answer (score 1):

I've done some workaround utility function, using imagesLoaded jquery plugin:
https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

```
            function waitForImageSize(src, func, ctx){
                if(!ctx)ctx = window;
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = src;
                $(img).imagesLoaded($.proxy(function(){
                    var w = this.img.innerWidth||this.img.naturalWidth;
                    var h = this.img.innerHeight||this.img.naturalHeight;
                    this.func.call(this.ctx, w, h, this.img);
                },{img: img, func: func, ctx: ctx}));
            },
```

You can use this by passing url, function and its context. Function is performed after image is loaded and return created image, its width and height.

```
waitForImageSize("image.png", function(w,h){alert(w+","+h)},this)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the image is already used, you sholud:

1. set image simensions to initial

   image.css('width', 'initial');
   image.css('height', 'initial');
2. get dimensions

   var originalWidth = $(this).width();
   var originalHeight = $(this).height();

Answer (score 1):

You can use the naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties of the HTML image element. (Here's more [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)).

You would use it like this:

```
//you need a reference to the DOM element, not a jQuery object. It would be better if you can use document.getElementByTagsName or ID or any other native method
var pic = $("img")[0];
var pic_real_width = pic.naturalWidth;
var pic_real_height = pic.naturalHeight;
```

It seems like this works in all browsers except on IE from version 8 and below.

Comment: Yeah, no more IE8 :D

Answer (score 0):

I checked out the answer of Dio and it works great for me.

`$('#image').fadeIn(10,function () {var tmpW = $(this).width(); var tmpH = $(this).height(); });`

Make sure that you call all your functions aso. that handle with the image size in the recaller function of fadeIn().

Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I use different approach, simply make Ajax call to server to get image size when image object is in use.

```
//make json call to server to get image size
$.getJSON("http://server/getimagesize.php",
{"src":url},
SetImageWidth
);

//callback function
function SetImageWidth(data) {

    var wrap = $("div#image_gallery #image_wrap");

    //remove height
     wrap.find("img").removeAttr('height');
    //remove height
     wrap.find("img").removeAttr('width');

    //set image width
    if (data.width > 635) {
        wrap.find("img").width(635);
    }
    else {
         wrap.find("img").width(data.width);
    }
}
```

and of course server side code:

```
<?php

$image_width = 0;
$image_height = 0;

if (isset ($_REQUEST['src']) && is_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $_REQUEST['src'])) {

    $imageinfo = getimagesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_REQUEST['src']);
    if ($imageinfo) {
       $image_width=  $imageinfo[0];
       $image_height= $imageinfo[1];
    }
}

$arr = array ('width'=>$image_width,'height'=>$image_height);

echo json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Comment: this is not a great solution and will take longer than any other solution becouse of the AJAX loading.

Answer (score 0):

Another suggestion is to use [imagesLoaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded).

```
$("img").imagesLoaded(function(){
alert( $(this).width() );
alert( $(this).height() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works cross browser

```
var img = new Image();
$(img).bind('load error', function(e)
{
    $.data(img, 'dimensions', { 'width': img.width, 'height': img.height });                    
});
img.src = imgs[i];
```

get the dimensions by using

```
$(this).data('dimensions').width;
$(this).data('dimensions').height;
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                            var image = $("#fix_img");
                            var w = image.width();
                            var h = image.height();
                            var mr = 274/200;
                            var ir = w/h
                            if(ir > mr){
                                image.height(200);
                                image.width(200*ir);
                            } else{
                                image.width(274);
                                image.height(274/ir);
                            }
                        });
```

// This code helps to show image with 200*274 dimention

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cross browser solution that triggers an event when your selected images are loaded: http://desandro.github.io/imagesloaded/ you can look up the height and width within the imagesLoaded() function.

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this thread trying to find an answer for my own question. I was trying to get an image's width/height in a function AFTER the loader, and kept coming up with 0. I feel like this might be what you're looking for, though, as it works for me:

```
tempObject.image = $('<img />').attr({ 'src':"images/prod-" + tempObject.id + ".png", load:preloader });
xmlProjectInfo.push(tempObject);

function preloader() {
    imagesLoaded++;
    if (imagesLoaded >= itemsToLoad) { //itemsToLoad gets set elsewhere in code
        DetachEvent(this, 'load', preloader); //function that removes event listener
        drawItems();
    }   
}

function drawItems() {
    for(var i = 1; i <= xmlProjectInfo.length; i++)
        alert(xmlProjectInfo[i - 1].image[0].width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this repository in github!

Great Example to check the Width and Height using Javascript

https://github.com/AzizAK/ImageRealSize

---Edited is requested from some comments ..

Javascript code:

```
 function CheckImageSize(){
var image = document.getElementById("Image").files[0];
           createReader(image, function (w, h) {

                alert("Width is: " + w + " And Height is: "+h);
});            
}


  function  createReader(file, whenReady) {
        var reader = new FileReader;
        reader.onload = function (evt) {
            var image = new Image();
            image.onload = function (evt) {
                var width = this.width;
                var height = this.height;
                if (whenReady) whenReady(width, height);
            };
            image.src = evt.target.result;
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

and HTML code :

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Real Size</title>
<script src="ImageSize.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="file" id="Image"/>
<input type="button" value="Find the dimensions" onclick="CheckImageSize()"/>
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: if possible you can also add a few line of code here. as links might change over timw

Answer (score -1):

For functions where you do not want to alter the original placement or image.

```
$(this).clone().removeAttr("width").attr("width");
$(this).clone().removeAttr("height").attr("height);
```

Comment: This absolutely does not work. It will return undefined for both