# Adding parameter to URL?

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)

If I wanted to add 2 suppose name and id values to URL. How can I do that using JavaScript?

Suppose we have URL: `http://localhost/demo/`, then how to add these 2 parameters.

Comment: do you want something like this:
index.html?parameter1=val1&parameter2=val2

Comment: Is this what you are after? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript

Comment: yes i want the same like u r mentioning

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to redirect to a location with javascript, try:
`location.href="http://localhost/demo/?" + id + "=" + value + "&" + id2 + "=" + value2`

If you just want to modify what's in the navigation bar

`location.hash = id + "=" + value;`

Answer (score 0):

```
"http://localhost/demo/" + "?name=" + escape(name_var) + "&id=" + escape(id_var)
```

Comment: but how can i add in my code so that it can work properly....