# w3c markup validator ampersand (&) error

Tags: html, markup, w3c-validation

Is there any workaround for the w3c validation error for an `&` present in urls or some other place in HTML markup?
It says:

> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as `&amp;`.)

The ampersand in my case is a part of a url for gravatar thumbnail. This is the problematic part of a url:

> `c91588793296e2?s=50&d=http%3A%2F%`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

for each & sign you got write `&amp;`
in your example it would be:

```
c91588793296e2?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%
```

Comment: Note that it is not _always_ required to encode ampersands, although it’s probably easiest to just do it. See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands.

Comment: You can use a regexp detection to automatically add &amp;s where missing: `htmlOut = htmlOut.replaceAll("&(?![a-zA-Z]+;)", "&amp;");`

Comment: I have a login-with-facebook code that adds a lot of messy not encoded ampersands and creates validation errors. Should I really write code to correct the error of someone else? :/

Answer (score 9):

Use `&amp;` for literal ampersands, even in URLs.

http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html#amp

Answer (score 4):

Replace with `&amp;`

Answer (score 4):

should be:

`c91588793296e2?s=50&amp;d=http%3A%2F%.`

notice the `&amp;`

I know it feels wonky, but ampersands have to be encoded as html entities, which are confusingly denoted with ampersands.