# w3c error because of & in a record

Tags: php, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [w3c markup validator ampersand (&) error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441594/w3c-markup-validator-ampersand-error)

I am pulling records from a database to display but when I echo it W3C validator complains that there is & in the record.

I displays fine on the page. Is there something I can do to clean the string?

Comment: Use `&amp;` instead of `&` - the validator should tell you that, though

Comment: the problem that when user put data into the database they use & and not &amp; so I have no control over the data going in

Comment: If you have no control over the data going in, you probably have serious XSS and SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @KeithPower — If you are letting users manually write HTML and aren't ensuring it is valid HTML before accepting it, then invalid HTML is to be expected.

Answer (score 3):

Presumably the error you are seeing is followed by this explanation:

> An entity reference was found in the document, but there is no reference by that name defined. Often this is caused by misspelling the reference name, unencoded ampersands, or by leaving off the trailing semicolon (`;`). The most common cause of this error is unencoded ampersands in URLs as described by the WDG in "Ampersands in URLs".
>
> Entity references start with an ampersand (`&`) and end with a semicolon (`;`). If you want to use a literal ampersand in your document you must encode it as "`&amp;`" (even inside URLs!). Be careful to end entity references with a semicolon or your entity reference may get interpreted in connection with the following text. Also keep in mind that named entity references are case-sensitive; &Aelig; and æ are different characters.

Pay attention to that explanation and replace `&` (meaning "Start a character reference") with  `&amp;` (meaning "An ampersand character").

PHP has a function for converting all characters with special meaning in HTML into character references that you should use whenever you have some plain text that you want to put into an HTML document. Use it: `htmlspecialchars()` first.