# php url string converts "&section=" to "§ion", which does not yield cURL response

Tags: php

I save a php string as 
$url = "http://example.com/index.php?q=board/ajax_**call&section**=get_messages";

The url when printed to screen displays as 
"http://example.com/index.php?q=board/ajax_**call§ion**=get_messages"  as  "&sect" gets auto converted to special char "§".

How can I prevent this so that I can call the correct URL using cURL .

Answer (score 2):

## Your Problem

The problem is that `&sect` is interpreted by the browser as the [HTML entity](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref) for `§`.<sup>*</sup> So, `&section` displays as `§ion`.

## The Solution

If you're going to print the URL itself, you need to escape the `&` and turn it into `&amp;`. You can do this automatically using [`htmlentities()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). Sample code:

```
<?php

$url = "http://example.com/index.php?q=board/ajax_call&section=get_messages";

echo "Without htmlentities(): " . $url . "\n";
// output: http://example.com/index.php?q=board/ajax_call&section=get_messages

echo "With htmlentities(): " . htmlentities($url) . "\n";
// output: http://example.com/index.php?q=board/ajax_call&amp;section=get_messages
```

Here's a [demo](https://3v4l.org/k0Abt).

## A Note About Security

Note that using `htmlentities()` here is a good idea for lots of other reasons. What if somebody used this URL?

```
http://example.com/index.php?q=board/ajax_call&section=get_messages<script src="http://evilsite/evil.js></script>
```

If you just dumped it out onto the screen, you have just included an evil JavaScript. Congratulations! You just hacked your user and, probably, got your own site hacked. This is a real problem called [XSS (Cross-Site Scripting)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). But if you call `htmlentities()` first, you get:

```
http://example.com/index.php?q=board/ajax_call&amp;section=get_messages&lt;script src=&quot;http://evilsite/evil.js&gt;&lt;/script&gt;
```

That's safe and won't actually run the evil script.

---

<sup>* Technically, the HTML entity is `&sect;`, with the semicolon, but nearly all browsers with treat it as an HTML entity with or without the semicolon. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15532395/2057919) for a good explanation.</sup>

Comment: Thanks Ed. However, when I use the $url with/without htmlentities() with  cURL to fetch the page, I get error response either ways. 

The solution I am after is :
How, can I get cURL to fetch the page that exists at 
"http://example.com/index.php?q=board/ajax_call&section=get_messages"

Comment: @AjayGoel Well, that's a different problem, and it's impossible to answer based on what you've posted -- you haven't shared any code related to how you're trying to use cURL. If this answer helped you, please consider accepting it. To ask more specifically about cURL, you can post a new question and link to this one if it helps provide some context.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `&` to `&amp;`.

(See [w3c markup validator ampersand (&) error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4441594/978917) for a bit more information.)