# ECHO not displaying Text Properly

Tags: php

I have written the below code:

```
<?php
$text = 'class&section';
echo $text;
?>
```

But upon executing its giving me *class§ion* on my browser. Unable to understand why *&section* is displaying as *§ion*. Can any one help me?

Comment: Because [`&sect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_sign) is an HTML entity. Use `htmlspecialchars` on your string to encode each individual character first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [php url string converts "&section=" to "§ion", which does not yield cURL response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39970170/php-url-string-converts-section-to-ion-which-does-not-yield-curl-respons)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&sect` is a HTML entity, so you must use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` before outputting this to the browser. **For the difference between these 2 functions, please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46483/htmlentities-vs-htmlspecialchars)**.

Your code could be rewritten to the following:

```
<?php
$text = 'class&section';
echo htmlspecialchars($text);
?>
```