# How can I add or update a query string parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string

With javascript how can I add a query string parameter to the url if not present or if it present, update the current value? I am using jquery for my client side development.

Comment: It seems like I've written the "parseQueryString" function in JavaScript about 100 times over my career. It's not hard. Key points, `String#split` takes a second parameter for max splits. jQuery's `map` will also be helpful.

Comment: This SO post also has many solutions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery

Comment: Some people are taking this question to mean "how to change the URL in the address bar" and others "how to change any URL variable"

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript

Answer (score 519, accepted):

I wrote the following function which accomplishes what I want to achieve:

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}
```

Comment: This answer doesn't work when there is a hash in the URI - query strings must be placed before the hash, else they don't get sent to the server. http://jsfiddle.net/4yXzR/

Comment: Limit separator variable scoping to local function by adding
    `var` just before separator declaration.

Comment: Nice!  @greg: you are right - see my answer for a variant which should cope with hash tags

Comment: I think, you should add `value = encodeURIComponent(value);` in the first line, otherwise line breaks are not escaped correctly.

Comment: What is the logic behind the mixture of single and double quotes?

Comment: @amateur will it replace key like names[0]='n1'?

Comment: This will take care of the hash as well: https://gist.github.com/niyazpk/f8ac616f181f6042d1e0

Comment: Can you please create same regex for me to add the new parameters after # (not after ? mark) ?

Comment: Maybe a nitpicky stylistic choice, but it might be better not to mutate the `uri` parameter to keep the function from surprising the programmer by mutating an object passed in as an argument, especially since you are explicitly returning the value for the new URI from the function, which makes it appear that you don't mean `uri` to be an "out" parameter.

Comment: The `key` must be escaped before creating the `RegExp`. You can use this: `function escapeRegExp(str) { return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"); }`. This allows for parameters like `&filter[1]=john`.

Comment: @rahul see my answer below

Comment: Can someone explain why this requires the URL as a parameter? And why it returns the URL?  Like, what is the use case here?  Something like `window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter(window.location.href, 'foo', 'bar')`?  Why  not just `updateQueryStringParameter('foo', 'bar')`?

Comment: This functions messes up anchors. a) The RegExp treats anchors as part of the value if the value is last in the URI. b) The else branch puts the anchor before the key-value-pair.

Comment: Fails more test cases than it passes. test cases and complete function:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529943/8385841

Comment: The final answer in the link given above in @Niyaz's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter#comment41746301_6021027) is the ultimate answer

Comment: URLSearchParams is more useful today

Answer (score 367):

**Update (2020):** URLSearchParams is now [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams#Browser_compatibility) by all modern browsers.

The [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) utility can be useful for this in combination with `window.location.search`. For example:

```
if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    searchParams.set("foo", "bar");
    window.location.search = searchParams.toString();
}
```

Now `foo` has been set to `bar` regardless of whether or not it already existed.

However, the above assignment to `window.location.search` will cause a page load, so if that's not desirable use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) as follows:

```
if ('URLSearchParams' in window) {
    var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)
    searchParams.set("foo", "bar");
    var newRelativePathQuery = window.location.pathname + '?' + searchParams.toString();
    history.pushState(null, '', newRelativePathQuery);
}
```

Now you don't need to write your own regex or logic to handle the possible existence of query strings.

<del>**However, [browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams) is poor as it's currently experimental and only in use in recent versions of Chrome, Firefox, Safari, iOS Safari, Android Browser, Android Chrome and Opera. Use with a [polyfill](https://github.com/WebReflection/url-search-params) if you do decide to use it.**</del>

Comment: polly fill, is not good, 

`Unable to set property '__URLSearchParams__:0.8503766759030615' of undefined or null reference`

on ie11 you get that error. it's not a pollyfill if it doesn't work as a fallback.

Comment: Update __2019__: Browser support is now good for most browsers except IE and some small mobile browsers. New pollyfill of ungap easily covers that: https://github.com/ungap/url-search-params

Comment: Perfect answer, however it doesnt handle usecase when hashtag is present in the url. Simple append of hash to the end of `newRelativePathQuery` does the trick: `var newRelativePathQuery = window.location.pathname + '?' + searchParams.toString() + window.location.hash;`

Comment: I find URL easier to use than URLSearchParams 
`const url = new URL(window.location);
url.searchParams.set("foo", "bar");
window.location = url;`

Answer (score 196):

I have expanded the solution and combined it with another that I found to replace/update/remove the querystring parameters based on the users input and taking the urls anchor into consideration.

Not supplying a value will remove the parameter, supplying one will add/update the parameter. If no URL is supplied, it will be grabbed from window.location

```
function UpdateQueryString(key, value, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)(.*)", "gi"),
        hash;

    if (re.test(url)) {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            return url.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2$3');
        } 
        else {
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0].replace(re, '$1$3').replace(/(&|\?)$/, '');
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) {
                url += '#' + hash[1];
            }
            return url;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            var separator = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '&' : '?';
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0] + separator + key + '=' + value;
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) {
                url += '#' + hash[1];
            }
            return url;
        }
        else {
            return url;
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

There was a bug when removing the first parameter in the querystring, I have reworked the regex and test to include a fix.

**Second Update**

As suggested by @JarónBarends - Tweak value check to check against undefined and null to allow setting 0 values

**Third Update**

There was a bug where removing a querystring variable directly before a hashtag would lose the hashtag symbol which has been fixed

**Fourth Update**

Thanks @rooby for pointing out a regex optimization in the first RegExp object.
Set initial regex to ([?&]) due to issue with using (\?|&) found by @YonatanKarni

**Fifth Update**

Removing declaring hash var in if/else statement

Comment: Just checking the 'truthiness' of `value` will cause this to remove variables from the querystring when you set their value to 0. so instead of `if (value) {}` you should use `if (typeOf value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {}`

Comment: In the RegExp ([?|&]) should really be ([?&])

Comment: Funny how that carried over from the original solution - could also use (\?|&)

Comment: getting a "invalid regular exception / invalid group" exception on regex creation in chrome Version 31.0.1650.63, solved by returning the beginning to be "([?&])"

Comment: @YonatanKarni that's interesting, my quick test worked but I'll revert it to that until I have time to look into it thanks

Comment: Not that this matters except for me being OCD, but the variable `hash` is declared twice ;)

Comment: @wlingke, that's true - but only within the cases that it's used (it's unused half the time) so only once within a flow of logic. Not sure where I stand on that :)

Comment: @ellemayo haha like I said - just being OCD since Javascript doesn't have blocks.

Comment: you're declaring the hash var inside the first if, but using it in the "else" block, downvoting

Comment: @knocte thank you for the downvote - I was declaring it in the else block as well - "var separator, hash;" - but I've moved my declaration to the top of the function as per wlingke's original block scope suggestion

Comment: I don't see the declaration of "var hash", where is it?

Comment: oh, I guess you can do `var re = foo, hash;` ? it's not very clear/readable though, please put the hash var the first, before `re`

Comment: A linters worst nightmare :/

Comment: The `key` must be escaped before creating the `RegExp`. You can use this: `function escapeRegExp(str) { return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&"); }`. This allows for parameters like `&filter[1]=john`.

Comment: This is probably the most correct answer here, other than it doesn't escape values and it doesn't replace parameters that existed but were not assigned a value (`http://abc.def/?a&b&c`). It's also way more code than it needs to be. Check my solution at the bottom of the page.

Comment: It worked like a charm. It also worked on SharePoint REST API Search Url as well. Thank you

Comment: It doesn't work with arrays. For example it will append a new `arr[key]=value` to the end of URL even when an `arr[key]` parameter exists on the URL. So instead of updating the existing parameter, it will add a new one to the URL. Can you fix it please?

Comment: fails for: http://example.com/? and  http://example.com/?param
Better:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23529943/8385841

Answer (score 51):

You can use the browser's native [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) to do this in a very simple way, where `key` and `value` are your parameter name and parameter value respectively.

```js
const url = new URL(location.href);
url.searchParams.set(key, value);
```

This will preserve everything about the URL and only change or add the one query param.

You can then do whatever you want with the `url` object. Examples:

```js
// Log the URL string.
console.log(url.href);

// Go to the URL.
location.assign(url);

// Go to the URL, but overwrite this history entry.
location.replace(url);

// Same as `location.assign` without reloading.
history.pushState(null, '', url);

// Same as `location.replace` without reloading.
history.replaceState(null, '', url);
```

Answer (score 46):

Based on @amateur's answer (and now incorporating the fix from @j_walker_dev comment), but taking into account the comment about hash tags in the url I use the following:

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)", "i");
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  } else {
    var hash =  '';
    if( uri.indexOf('#') !== -1 ){
        hash = uri.replace(/.*#/, '#');
        uri = uri.replace(/#.*/, '');
    }
    var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";    
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value + hash;
  }
}
```

Edited to fix `[?|&]` in regex which should of course be `[?&]` as pointed out in the comments

**Edit:** Alternative version to support **removing** URL params as well.  I have used `value === undefined` as the way to indicate removal.  Could use `value === false` or even a separate input param as wanted.

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)", "i");
  if( value === undefined ) {
    if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1$2').replace(/[?&]$/, '').replaceAll(/([?&])&+/g, '$1').replace(/[?&]#/, '#');
  } else {
    return uri;
  }
  } else {
    if (uri.match(re)) {
      return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  } else {
    var hash =  '';
    if( uri.indexOf('#') !== -1 ){
        hash = uri.replace(/.*#/, '#');
        uri = uri.replace(/#.*/, '');
    }
    var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";    
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value + hash;
    }
  }
}
```

See it in action at https://jsfiddle.net/cdt16wex/

Comment: Much cleaner. FYI for angular ui-router users who can have "?" in the hash as well. Moving the `var separator` line to right above the return fixes a bug with "/app#/cool?fun=true". This would choose a "&" as the separator even though there are no real query string params yet. Only client ones.

Comment: As pointed out in comments on other answers, `[?|&]` should be just `[?&]` (otherwise will match `|`).

Comment: Yeah, `"([?|&])"` is not good. Please fix this as either `var re = new RegExp("(?|&)" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)", "i");` or `var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)", "i");` (a nice extension in other ways!)

Comment: ok, sorry, `var re = new RegExp("(?|&)" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)", "i");` doesn't work, the second one does

Comment: It seems like this version doesn't support removing a query string parameter by omitting the value. Am I right?

Comment: Not as such @jimmykup.  Could adapat it to do so quite eaisly though

Comment: Thanks, great edit. In the JSFiddle if I repeatedly remove and add parameters eventually the URL ends up looking like this: `https://www.example.com/?&&&&#baz`And if I remove just the `foo` parameter I get this: `https://www.example.com/?&bar=2#baz` with both ? and & in there even though there's only one parameter.

Comment: Extra & symbols in the parameters should be harmless I think. They were when i checked $_REQUEST in PHP at least.

Comment: Unlike the others, this one works with even if the URL has hash.

Comment: Before creating the `separator` variable, the `uri` variable must be checked. if its end with `?` then it should be removed.
`uri = uri.slice(-1) == '?' ? uri.slice(0, -1) : uri;`

Comment: @kooroshsafeashrafi: You could for aesthetics, but I don't think it's strictly needed.  As far as I'm aware, empty variables are allowed.  I.e. `?foo=bar&baz=1` is functionally the same as `?&foo=bar&baz=1`.  You end up with two query parmeters, `foo` and `baz`, on the server-side code.  I can't actually find the specification for the query part, but all the servers I've used have behaved this way I think.  I just did a test using an apache/PHP back-end and that certainly does.

Comment: @Adam I think I could not convey what I meant. I'm talking about URLs that are like `https://example.com/something?` (ending in a question mark). It is a very rare condition but it can occur. So we need `uri = uri.slice(-1) == '?' ? uri.slice(0, -1) : uri;` before creating `separator`

Answer (score 25):

Thanks to modern javascript, node.js and browsers support, we can get out of 3rd-party library whirlpool (jquery, query-string etc.) and DRY ourselves.

Here are javascript(node.js) and typescript version for a function that adds or updates query params of given url:

### Javascript

```js
const getUriWithParam = (baseUrl, params) => {
  const Url = new URL(baseUrl);
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(Url.search);
  for (const key in params) {
    if (params[key] !== undefined) {
      urlParams.set(key, params[key]);
    }
  }
  Url.search = urlParams.toString();
  return Url.toString();
};

console.info('expected: https://example.com/?foo=bar');
console.log(getUriWithParam("https://example.com", {foo: "bar"}));

console.info('expected: https://example.com/slug?foo=bar#hash');
console.log(getUriWithParam("https://example.com/slug#hash", {foo: "bar"}));

console.info('expected: https://example.com/?bar=baz&foo=bar');
console.log(getUriWithParam("https://example.com?bar=baz", {foo: "bar"}));

console.info('expected: https://example.com/?foo=baz&bar=baz');
console.log(getUriWithParam("https://example.com?foo=bar&bar=baz", {foo: "baz"}));
```

### Typescript

```js
const getUriWithParam = (
  baseUrl: string,
  params: Record<string, any>
): string => {
  const Url = new URL(baseUrl);
  const urlParams: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams(Url.search);
  for (const key in params) {
    if (params[key] !== undefined) {
      urlParams.set(key, params[key]);
    }
  }
  Url.search = urlParams.toString();
  return Url.toString();
};
```

### For React Native

`URL` is not implemented in React Native. So you have to install [react-native-url-polyfill](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-url-polyfill) beforehand.

### For object params

See the second solution [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/11792577)

Comment: This should be the best choice

Comment: IE is not supported

Answer (score 20):

Here is my library to do that: https://github.com/Mikhus/jsurl

```
var u = new Url;
u.query.param='value'; // adds or replaces the param
alert(u)
```

Answer (score 15):

If it's not set or want to update with a new value you can use:

```
window.location.search = 'param=value'; // or param=new_value
```

This is in simple Javascript, by the way.

**EDIT**

You may want to try using the jquery [query-object](https://plugins.jquery.com/query-object/) plugin

> window.location.search =
>   jQuery.query.set("param", 5);

Comment: this wont maintain any other query string parameters on the url though.

Comment: you are right, I apologize.. as an update, I added another option to my answer :)

Comment: This is not working, because it doesn't reset a value. "add or update"

Answer (score 14):

I realize this question is old and has been answered to death, but here's my stab at it. I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here because I was using the currently accepted answer and the mishandling of URL fragments recently bit me in a project.

The function is below. It's quite long, but it was made to be as resilient as possible. I would love suggestions for shortening/improving it. I put together a small [jsFiddle test suite](http://jsfiddle.net/dominic_p/2ncMs/) for it (or other similar functions). If a function can pass every one of the tests there, I say it's probably good to go.

**Update:** I came across a cool function for [using the DOM to parse URLs](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/), so I incorporated that technique here. It makes the function shorter and more reliable. Props to the author of that function.

```
/**
 * Add or update a query string parameter. If no URI is given, we use the current
 * window.location.href value for the URI.
 * 
 * Based on the DOM URL parser described here:
 * http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/parsing-urls-with-the-dom/
 *
 * @param   (string)    uri     Optional: The URI to add or update a parameter in
 * @param   (string)    key     The key to add or update
 * @param   (string)    value   The new value to set for key
 *
 * Tested on Chrome 34, Firefox 29, IE 7 and 11
 */
function update_query_string( uri, key, value ) {

    // Use window URL if no query string is provided
    if ( ! uri ) { uri = window.location.href; }

    // Create a dummy element to parse the URI with
    var a = document.createElement( 'a' ), 

        // match the key, optional square brackets, an equals sign or end of string, the optional value
        reg_ex = new RegExp( key + '((?:\\[[^\\]]*\\])?)(=|$)(.*)' ),

        // Setup some additional variables
        qs,
        qs_len,
        key_found = false;

    // Use the JS API to parse the URI 
    a.href = uri;

    // If the URI doesn't have a query string, add it and return
    if ( ! a.search ) {

        a.search = '?' + key + '=' + value;

        return a.href;
    }

    // Split the query string by ampersands
    qs = a.search.replace( /^\?/, '' ).split( /&(?:amp;)?/ );
    qs_len = qs.length; 

    // Loop through each query string part
    while ( qs_len > 0 ) {

        qs_len--;

        // Remove empty elements to prevent double ampersands
        if ( ! qs[qs_len] ) { qs.splice(qs_len, 1); continue; }

        // Check if the current part matches our key
        if ( reg_ex.test( qs[qs_len] ) ) {

            // Replace the current value
            qs[qs_len] = qs[qs_len].replace( reg_ex, key + '$1' ) + '=' + value;

            key_found = true;
        }
    }   

    // If we haven't replaced any occurrences above, add the new parameter and value
    if ( ! key_found ) { qs.push( key + '=' + value ); }

    // Set the new query string
    a.search = '?' + qs.join( '&' );

    return a.href;
}
```

Comment: This looks really good, solid test cases + using the DOM as URL parser.
I did find two cases though:
http://example.com/?param=val&  => http://example.com/?param=val&&new=key
--double &
and
http://example.com/team => http://example.com/team?new=key
expected: team/?new=key
some redirect /team?new=key to /team/ and the queries are lost.

Comment: Thanks for the failing test case. I updated the fiddle. That first one is tough. Any ideas on how to fix the function for it? The second should be handled no problem and is already covered in the test suite. Maybe I don't understand you though. Feel free to fork the test fiddle to demonstrate what you're seeing.

Comment: I added some test cases i ran into and workarounds. I tried to use the DOM as much as possible. Primarily i needed this to also work for relative links within the same domain.
http://jsfiddle.net/Timar/7sjrhbm3/

Comment: Why is it considered a good thing to use the DOM for something like this?

Comment: @braed I like the approach because it leaves the heavy lifting to the browser. As you see from a lot of answers here, this problem is not as simple as it seems. There are A LOT of corner cases that a solution needs to cover. Most of them are covered for free when you leverage the DOM.

Comment: @DominicP I'd love some examples of those edge cases and how using the DOM covers them. I wouldn't have even considered creating a dummy element etc here. Can you point me in the direction of some reading material?

Comment: @braed sure just take a look at the test suite I linked in the answer. A lot of the solutions here that don't rely on the DOM fail it because they don't account for all of the edge cases listed. As for reading, it might be instructive to look at the [URL module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) for node.js. It's not directly related, but it gives you an idea of some of the complexity involved in URL strings.

Comment: I think my misconception was that "using the DOM" was a common approach to solving issues in Javascript, but actually it's just useful here because anchor elements have their own attributes such as `hash` and `search`.

Answer (score 11):

window.location.search is read/write.

However - modifying the query string will redirect the page you're on and cause a refresh from the server.

If what you're attempting to do is maintain client side state (and potentially make it bookmark-able), you'll want to modify the URL hash instead of the query string, which keeps you on the same page (window.location.hash is read/write). This is how web sites like twitter.com do this.

You'll also want the back button to work, you'll have to bind javascript events to the hash change event, a good plugin for that is http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: Twitter no longer modifies hash! Hash is dead, welcome the **History API**!

Comment: it's far from dead. i think you are living in a magical dreamland where legacy browser compatibility is of no concern. this may be the case for you, but it's certainly not the case for the rest of us (or in fact the majority of us). perhaps *dying* is more appropriate...

Comment: One year later, It looks like the only semi-recent browser that does not support it is IE 9

Answer (score 9):

Here's my approach: The `location.params()` function (shown below) can be used as a getter or setter.  Examples:

Given the URL is `http://example.com/?foo=bar&baz#some-hash`,

1. `location.params()` will return an object with all the query parameters: `{foo: 'bar', baz: true}`.
2. `location.params('foo')` will return `'bar'`.
3. `location.params({foo: undefined, hello: 'world', test: true})` will change the URL to `http://example.com/?baz&hello=world&test#some-hash`.

Here is the `params()` function, which can optionally be assigned to the `window.location` object.

```
location.params = function(params) {
  var obj = {}, i, parts, len, key, value;

  if (typeof params === 'string') {
    value = location.search.match(new RegExp('[?&]' + params + '=?([^&]*)[&#$]?'));
    return value ? value[1] : undefined;
  }

  var _params = location.search.substr(1).split('&');

  for (i = 0, len = _params.length; i < len; i++) {
    parts = _params[i].split('=');
    if (! parts[0]) {continue;}
    obj[parts[0]] = parts[1] || true;
  }

  if (typeof params !== 'object') {return obj;}

  for (key in params) {
    value = params[key];
    if (typeof value === 'undefined') {
      delete obj[key];
    } else {
      obj[key] = value;
    }
  }

  parts = [];
  for (key in obj) {
    parts.push(key + (obj[key] === true ? '' : '=' + obj[key]));
  }

  location.search = parts.join('&');
};
```

Comment: It's bad practice to mutate things you didn't make in ways they aren't meant to be mutated. What if, for example, a `params` field is added to the built-in `Location` class? Then this code would conflict with that. Or perhaps widespread use of this code would prevent such a field from ever being added, as was the case with `contains` on strings and arrays--they had to name it `includes` instead due to widespread overwriting of `contains`.

Answer (score 6):

I know this is quite old but i want to fires my **working version** in here.

```js
function addOrUpdateUrlParam(uri, paramKey, paramVal) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + paramKey + "=[^&#]*", "i");
  if (re.test(uri)) {
    uri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + paramKey + "=" + paramVal);
  } else {
    var separator = /\?/.test(uri) ? "&" : "?";
    uri = uri + separator + paramKey + "=" + paramVal;
  }
  return uri;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#paramKey,#paramValue').on('change', function() {
    if ($('#paramKey').val() != "" && $('#paramValue').val() != "") {
      $('#uri').val(addOrUpdateUrlParam($('#uri').val(), $('#paramKey').val(), $('#paramValue').val()));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input style="width:100%" type="text" id="uri" value="http://www.example.com/text.php">
<label style="display:block;">paramKey
  <input type="text" id="paramKey">
</label>
<label style="display:block;">paramValue
  <input type="text" id="paramValue">
</label>
```

**NOTE** This is a modified version of @elreimundo

Comment: Tested with jsFiddle from Dominic P:

FAIL :: http://example.com/? :: http://example.com/?&param=new
Expected: http://example.com/?param=new
FAIL :: http://example.com/?param :: http://example.com/?param&param=new
Expected: http://example.com/?param=new
FAIL :: http://example.com/?param=&amp;param2 :: http://example.com/?param=new&amp;param2
Expected: http://example.com/?param=new&param2
FAIL :: http://example.com/?param2=val&param[]=val :: http://example.com/?param2=val&param[]=val&param=new
Expected: http://example.com/?param2=val&param[]=new

Answer (score 6):

It's so simple with [`URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), supported in all modern browsers ([caniuse](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams)).

```js
let p = new URLSearchParams();
p.set("foo", "bar");
p.set("name", "Jack & Jill?");
console.log("http://example.com/?" + p.toString());
```

If you want to modify the existing URL, construct the object like this: `new URLSearchParams(window.location.search)` and assign the string to `window.location.search`.

Answer (score 3):

My take [from here](https://snipt.net/andreyvit/parsing-encoding-and-updating-url-params-in-javascript/) (compatible with "use strict"; does not really use jQuery):

```
function decodeURIParams(query) {
  if (query == null)
    query = window.location.search;
  if (query[0] == '?')
    query = query.substring(1);

  var params = query.split('&');
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i++) {
    var param = params[i];
    var pos = param.indexOf('=');
    if (pos >= 0) {
        var key = decodeURIComponent(param.substring(0, pos));
        var val = decodeURIComponent(param.substring(pos + 1));
        result[key] = val;
    } else {
        var key = decodeURIComponent(param);
        result[key] = true;
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function encodeURIParams(params, addQuestionMark) {
  var pairs = [];
  for (var key in params) if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var value = params[key];
    if (value != null) /* matches null and undefined */ {
      pairs.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(value))
    }
  }
  if (pairs.length == 0)
    return '';
  return (addQuestionMark ? '?' : '') + pairs.join('&');
}

//// alternative to $.extend if not using jQuery:
// function mergeObjects(destination, source) {
//   for (var key in source) if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
//     destination[key] = source[key];
//   }
//   return destination;
// }

function navigateWithURIParams(newParams) {
  window.location.search = encodeURIParams($.extend(decodeURIParams(), newParams), true);
}
```

Example usage:

```
// add/update parameters
navigateWithURIParams({ foo: 'bar', boz: 42 });

// remove parameter
navigateWithURIParams({ foo: null });

// submit the given form by adding/replacing URI parameters (with jQuery)
$('.filter-form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  navigateWithURIParams(decodeURIParams($(this).serialize()));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the answer @ellemayo gave, I came up with the following solution that allows for disabling of the hash tag if desired:

```
function updateQueryString(key, value, options) {
    if (!options) options = {};

    var url = options.url || location.href;
    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)(.*)", "gi"), hash;

    hash = url.split('#');
    url = hash[0];
    if (re.test(url)) {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            url = url.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2$3');
        } else {
            url = url.replace(re, '$1$3').replace(/(&|\?)$/, '');
        }
    } else if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
        var separator = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '&' : '?';
        url = url + separator + key + '=' + value;
    }

    if ((typeof options.hash === 'undefined' || options.hash) &&
        typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null)
        url += '#' + hash[1];
    return url;
}
```

Call it like this:

```
updateQueryString('foo', 'bar', {
    url: 'http://my.example.com#hash',
    hash: false
});
```

Results in:

```
http://my.example.com?foo=bar
```

Comment: Stylistic quibble: `typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null` is more explicit, but `value != null` means the same thing and is more concise.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a shorter version that takes care of

- query with or without a given parameter
- query with multiple parameter values
- query containing hash

Code:

```
var setQueryParameter = function(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])("+ key + "=)[^&#]*", "g");
  if (uri.match(re)) 
    return uri.replace(re, '$1$2' + value);

  // need to add parameter to URI
  var paramString = (uri.indexOf('?') < 0 ? "?" : "&") + key + "=" + value;
  var hashIndex = uri.indexOf('#');
  if (hashIndex < 0)
    return uri + paramString;
  else
    return uri.substring(0, hashIndex) + paramString + uri.substring(hashIndex);
}
```

The **regex** description can be found [here](https://regex101.com/r/zR7jM0/3).

**NOTE**: This solution is based on @amateur answer, but with many improvements.

Answer (score 2):

Code that appends a list of parameters to an existing url using ES6 and jQuery:

```
class UrlBuilder {
    static appendParametersToUrl(baseUrl, listOfParams) {

        if (jQuery.isEmptyObject(listOfParams)) {
            return baseUrl;
        }

        const newParams = jQuery.param(listOfParams);

        let partsWithHash = baseUrl.split('#');
        let partsWithParams = partsWithHash[0].split('?');

        let previousParams = '?' + ((partsWithParams.length === 2) ? partsWithParams[1] + '&' : '');
        let previousHash = (partsWithHash.length === 2) ? '#' + partsWithHash[1] : '';

        return partsWithParams[0] + previousParams + newParams + previousHash;
    }
}
```

Where listOfParams is like

```
const listOfParams = {
    'name_1': 'value_1',
    'name_2': 'value_2',
    'name_N': 'value_N',
};
```

Example of Usage:

```
    UrlBuilder.appendParametersToUrl(urlBase, listOfParams);
```

Fast tests:

```
    url = 'http://hello.world';
    console.log('=> ', UrlParameters.appendParametersToUrl(url, null));
    // Output:  http://hello.world

    url = 'http://hello.world#h1';
    console.log('=> ', UrlParameters.appendParametersToUrl(url, null));
    // Output:  http://hello.world#h1

    url = 'http://hello.world';
    params = {'p1': 'v1', 'p2': 'v2'};
    console.log('=> ', UrlParameters.appendParametersToUrl(url, params));
    // Output: http://hello.world?p1=v1&p2=v2

    url = 'http://hello.world?p0=v0';
    params = {'p1': 'v1', 'p2': 'v2'};
    console.log('=> ', UrlParameters.appendParametersToUrl(url, params));
    // Output: http://hello.world?p0=v0&p1=v1&p2=v2

    url = 'http://hello.world#h1';
    params = {'p1': 'v1', 'p2': 'v2'};
    console.log('=> ', UrlParameters.appendParametersToUrl(url, params));
   // Output: http://hello.world?p1=v1&p2=v2#h1

    url = 'http://hello.world?p0=v0#h1';
    params = {'p1': 'v1', 'p2': 'v2'};
    console.log('=> ', UrlParameters.appendParametersToUrl(url, params));
    // Output: http://hello.world?p0=v0&p1=v1&p2=v2#h1
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just a small tweak of [ellemayo's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11654596/4781067) answer. It will automatically update the URL instead of just returning the updated string.

```
function _updateQueryString(key, value, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;

    let updated = ''
    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)(.*)", "gi"),
        hash;

    if (re.test(url)) {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            updated = url.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2$3');
        } 
        else {
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0].replace(re, '$1$3').replace(/(&|\?)$/, '');
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) {
                url += '#' + hash[1];
            }
            updated = url;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (typeof value !== 'undefined' && value !== null) {
            var separator = url.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? '&' : '?';
            hash = url.split('#');
            url = hash[0] + separator + key + '=' + value;
            if (typeof hash[1] !== 'undefined' && hash[1] !== null) {
                url += '#' + hash[1];
            }
            updated = url;
        }
        else {
            updated = url;
        }
    }

    window.history.replaceState({ path: updated }, '', updated);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To give an code example for modifying `window.location.search` as suggested by Gal and tradyblix:

```
var qs = window.location.search || "?";
var param = key + "=" + value; // remember to URI encode your parameters
if (qs.length > 1) {
    // more than just the question mark, so append with ampersand
    qs = qs + "&";
}
qs = qs + param;
window.location.search = qs;
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach **without using regular expressions**. Supports 'hash' anchors at the end of the url as well as multiple question mark charcters (?). Should be slightly faster than the regular expression approach.

```
function setUrlParameter(url, key, value) {
  var parts = url.split("#", 2), anchor = parts.length > 1 ? "#" + parts[1] : '';
  var query = (url = parts[0]).split("?", 2);
  if (query.length === 1) 
    return url + "?" + key + "=" + value + anchor;

  for (var params = query[query.length - 1].split("&"), i = 0; i < params.length; i++)
    if (params[i].toLowerCase().startsWith(key.toLowerCase() + "="))
      return params[i] = key + "=" + value, query[query.length - 1] = params.join("&"), query.join("?") + anchor;

  return url + "&" + key + "=" + value + anchor
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this function to add, remove and modify query string parameter from URL based on jquery

```
/**
@param String url
@param object param {key: value} query parameter
*/
function modifyURLQuery(url, param){
    var value = {};

    var query = String(url).split('?');

    if (query[1]) {
        var part = query[1].split('&');

        for (i = 0; i < part.length; i++) {
            var data = part[i].split('=');

            if (data[0] && data[1]) {
                value[data[0]] = data[1];
            }
        }
    }

    value = $.extend(value, param);

    // Remove empty value
    for (i in value){
        if(!value[i]){
            delete value[i];
        }
    }

    // Return url with modified parameter
    if(value){
        return query[0] + '?' + $.param(value);
    } else {
        return query[0];
    }
}
```

Add new and modify existing parameter to url

```
var new_url = modifyURLQuery("http://google.com?foo=34", {foo: 50, bar: 45});
// Result: http://google.com?foo=50&bar=45
```

Remove existing

```
var new_url = modifyURLQuery("http://google.com?foo=50&bar=45", {bar: null});
// Result: http://google.com?foo=50
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my slightly different approach to this, written as an excercise

```
function addOrChangeParameters( url, params )
{
  let splitParams = {};
  let splitPath = (/(.*)[?](.*)/).exec(url);
  if ( splitPath && splitPath[2] )
    splitPath[2].split("&").forEach( k => { let d = k.split("="); splitParams[d[0]] = d[1]; } );
  let newParams = Object.assign( splitParams, params );
  let finalParams = Object.keys(newParams).map( (a) => a+"="+newParams[a] ).join("&");
  return splitPath ? (splitPath[1] + "?" + finalParams) : (url + "?" + finalParams);
}
```

usage:

```
const url = "http://testing.com/path?empty&value1=test&id=3";

addOrChangeParameters( url, {value1:1, empty:"empty", new:0} )

"http://testing.com/path?empty=empty&value1=1&id=3&new=0"
```

Comment: this is a simple and awesome

Answer (score 0):

Java script code to find a specific query string and replace its value *

```
('input.letter').click(function () {
                //0- prepare values
                var qsTargeted = 'letter=' + this.value; //"letter=A";
                var windowUrl = '';
                var qskey = qsTargeted.split('=')[0];
                var qsvalue = qsTargeted.split('=')[1];
                //1- get row url
                var originalURL = window.location.href;
                //2- get query string part, and url
                if (originalURL.split('?').length > 1) //qs is exists
                {
                    windowUrl = originalURL.split('?')[0];
                    var qs = originalURL.split('?')[1];
                    //3- get list of query strings
                    var qsArray = qs.split('&');
                    var flag = false;
                    //4- try to find query string key
                    for (var i = 0; i < qsArray.length; i++) {
                        if (qsArray[i].split('=').length > 0) {
                            if (qskey == qsArray[i].split('=')[0]) {
                                //exists key
                                qsArray[i] = qskey + '=' + qsvalue;
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (!flag)//   //5- if exists modify,else add
                    {
                        qsArray.push(qsTargeted);
                    }
                    var finalQs = qsArray.join('&');
                    //6- prepare final url
                    window.location = windowUrl + '?' + finalQs;
                }
                else {
                    //6- prepare final url
                    //add query string
                    window.location = originalURL + '?' + qsTargeted;
                }
            })
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative method using the inbuilt properties of the anchor HTML element:

- Handles multi-valued parameters.
- No risk of modifying the # fragment, or anything other than the query string itself.
- May be a little easier to read? But it is longer.

```js
    var a = document.createElement('a'),

 getHrefWithUpdatedQueryString = function(param, value) {
     return updatedQueryString(window.location.href, param, value);
 },

 updatedQueryString = function(url, param, value) {
     /*
      A function which modifies the query string 
             by setting one parameter to a single value.

      Any other instances of parameter will be removed/replaced.
      */
     var fragment = encodeURIComponent(param) + 
                           '=' + encodeURIComponent(value);

     a.href = url;

     if (a.search.length === 0) {
  a.search = '?' + fragment;
     } else {
  var didReplace = false,
      // Remove leading '?'
      parts = a.search.substring(1)
  // Break into pieces
   .split('&'),

      reassemble = [],
      len = parts.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      
      var pieces = parts[i].split('=');
      if (pieces[0] === param) {
   if (!didReplace) {
       reassemble.push('&' + fragment);
       didReplace = true;
   }
      } else {
   reassemble.push(parts[i]);
      }
  }

  if (!didReplace) {
      reassemble.push('&' + fragment);
  }

  a.search = reassemble.join('&');
     }

     return a.href;
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to set multiple parameters at once:

```
function updateQueryStringParameters(uri, params) {
    for(key in params){
      var value = params[key],
          re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i"),
          separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
      if (uri.match(re)) {
        uri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
      }
      else {
        uri = uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
      }
    }
    return uri;
}
```

same function as @amateur's

if jslint gives you an error add this after the for loop

```
if(params.hasOwnProperty(key))
```

Comment: Doesn't handle hashes, or parameters not assigned a value(`http://abc.def/?a&b&c`).

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of awkward and unnecessarily complicated answers on this page. The highest rated one, @amateur's, is quite good, although it has a bit of unnecessary fluff in the RegExp. Here is a slightly more optimal solution with cleaner RegExp and a cleaner `replace` call:

```
function updateQueryStringParamsNoHash(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=[^&]*", "i");
  return re.test(uri)
       ? uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value)
       : uri + separator + key + "=" + value
  ;
}
```

As an added bonus, if `uri` is not a string, you won't get errors for trying to call `match` or `replace` on something that may not implement those methods.

And if you want to handle the case of a hash (and you've already done a check for properly formatted HTML), you can leverage the existing function instead of writing a new function containing the same logic:

```
function updateQueryStringParams(url, key, value) {
    var splitURL = url.split('#');
    var hash = splitURL[1];
    var uri = updateQueryStringParamsNoHash(splitURL[0]);
    return hash == null ? uri : uri + '#' + hash;
}
```

Or you can make some slight changes to @Adam's otherwise excellent answer:

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=[^&#]*", "i");
  if (re.test(uri)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value);
  } else {
    var matchData = uri.match(/^([^#]*)(#.*)?$/);
    var separator = /\?/.test(uri) ? "&" : "?";    
    return matchData[0] + separator + key + "=" + value + (matchData[1] || '');
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a missing bracket in the last function: var matchData = uri.match(/^([^#]*)(#.*)?$/

Comment: `separator` is not defined in `updateQueryStringParamsNoHash`. In `updateQueryStringParameter`, everything breaks down if the parameter you're replacing is not assigned a value (e.g. `http://abc.def/?a&b&c`).

Answer (score 0):

This should serve the purpose:

```
function updateQueryString(url, key, value) {
    var arr =  url.split("#");
    var url = arr[0];
    var fragmentId = arr[1];
    var updatedQS = "";
    if (url.indexOf("?") == -1) {
        updatedQS = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
    }
    else {
        updatedQS = addOrModifyQS(url.substring(url.indexOf("?") + 1), key, value); 
    }
    url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("?")) + "?" + updatedQS;
    if (typeof fragmentId !== 'undefined') {
        url = url + "#" + fragmentId;
    }
    return url;
}

function addOrModifyQS(queryStrings, key, value) {
    var oldQueryStrings = queryStrings.split("&");
    var newQueryStrings = new Array();
    var isNewKey = true;
    for (var i in oldQueryStrings) {
        var currItem = oldQueryStrings[i];
        var searchKey = key + "=";
        if (currItem.indexOf(searchKey) != -1) {
            currItem = encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value);
            isNewKey = false;
        }
        newQueryStrings.push(currItem);
    }
    if (isNewKey) {
        newQueryStrings.push(encodeURIComponent(key) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value));
    }
    return newQueryStrings.join("&");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By using `jQuery` we can do like below

```
var query_object = $.query_string;
query_object["KEY"] = "VALUE";
var new_url = window.location.pathname + '?'+$.param(query_object)
```

In variable `new_url` we will have new query parameters.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted something that:

- Uses the browser's native [URL API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
- Can add, update, get, or delete
- Expects the query string after the hash e.g. for single page applications

```js
function queryParam(options = {}) {

  var defaults = {
    method: 'set',
    url: window.location.href,
    key: undefined,
    value: undefined,
  }

  for (var prop in defaults) {
    options[prop] = typeof options[prop] !== 'undefined' ? options[prop] : defaults[prop]
  }

  const existing = (options.url.lastIndexOf('?') > options.url.lastIndexOf('#')) ? options.url.substr(options.url.lastIndexOf('?') + 1) : ''

  const query = new URLSearchParams(existing)

  if (options.method === 'set') {
    query.set(options.key, options.value)

    return `${options.url.replace(`?${existing}`, '')}?${query.toString()}`
  } else if (options.method === 'get') {
    const val = query.get(options.key)
    let result = val === null ? val : val.toString()

    return result
  } else if (options.method === 'delete') {
    query.delete(options.key)

    let result = `${options.url.replace(`?${existing}`, '')}?${query.toString()}`
    const lastChar = result.charAt(result.length - 1)

    if (lastChar === '?') {
      result = `${options.url.replace(`?${existing}`, '')}`
    }

    return result
  }
}

// Usage:
let url = 'https://example.com/sandbox/#page/'

url = queryParam({
  url,
  method: 'set',
  key: 'my-first-param',
  value: 'me'
})
console.log(url)

url = queryParam({
  url,
  method: 'set',
  key: 'my-second-param',
  value: 'you'
})
console.log(url)

url = queryParam({
  url,
  method: 'set',
  key: 'my-second-param',
  value: 'whomever'
})
console.log(url)

url = queryParam({
  url,
  method: 'delete',
  key: 'my-first-param'
})
console.log(url)

const mySecondParam = queryParam({
  url,
  method: 'get',
  key: 'my-second-param',
})
console.log(mySecondParam)

url = queryParam({
  url,
  method: 'delete',
  key: 'my-second-param'
})
console.log(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah I had an issue where my querystring would overflow and duplicate, but this was due to my own sluggishness. so I played a bit and worked up some js jquery(actualy sizzle) and C# magick.

So i just realized that after the server has done with the passed values, the values doesn't matter anymore, there is no reuse, if the client wanted to do the same thing evidently it will always be a new request, even if its the same parameters being passed. And thats all clientside, so some caching/cookies etc could be cool in that regards.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#ser').click(function () {
                SerializeIT();
            });
            function SerializeIT() {
                var baseUrl = "";
                baseUrl = getBaseUrlFromBrowserUrl(window.location.toString());
                var myQueryString = "";
                funkyMethodChangingStuff(); //whatever else before serializing and creating the querystring
                myQueryString = $('#fr2').serialize();
                window.location.replace(baseUrl + "?" + myQueryString);
            }
            function getBaseUrlFromBrowserUrl(szurl) {
                return szurl.split("?")[0];
            } 
            function funkyMethodChangingStuff(){
               //do stuff to whatever is in fr2
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fr2">
   <input type="text" name="qURL" value="http://somewhere.com" />
   <input type="text" name="qSPart" value="someSearchPattern" />
</div>
<button id="ser">Serialize! and go play with the server.</button>
```

C#:

```
    using System.Web;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;

    public partial class SomeCoolWebApp : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string weburl = string.Empty;
        string partName = string.Empty;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string loadurl = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
            string querySZ = null;
            int isQuery = loadurl.IndexOf('?');
            if (isQuery == -1) { 
                //If There Was no Query
            }
            else if (isQuery >= 1) {
                querySZ = (isQuery < loadurl.Length - 1) ? loadurl.Substring(isQuery + 1) : string.Empty;
                string[] getSingleQuery = querySZ.Split('?');
                querySZ = getSingleQuery[0];

                NameValueCollection qs = null;
                qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(querySZ);

                weburl = qs["qURL"];
                partName = qs["qSPart"];
                //call some great method thisPageRocks(weburl,partName); or whatever.
          }
      }
  }
```

> ***Okay criticism is welcome (this was a nightly concoction so feel free to note adjustments). If this helped at all, thumb it up, Happy Coding.***

No duplicates, each request as unique as you modified it, and due to how this is structured,easy to add more queries dynamicaly from wthin the dom.