# How to modify URL by JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

I want to remove the string `code=hads1328fas&` on my URL, so that

**BEFORE**

`http://example.com/main/index.php?code=hads1328fas&store=food#home`

**AFTER**

`http://example.com/main/index.php?store=food#home`

However, the string `code=hads1328fas&` may not always the same, so the code below won't works in this case.

```
var url = window.location.href;
url.replace('code=hads1328fas&')
```

Is there any way that is possible for the case?

Thanks

Comment: regular expressions are your friends :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [add or update query string parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter)

Comment: `"http://example.com/main/index.php?code=hads1328fas&store=food#home".replace(/code=[^&]*/, '')` Should do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression):

```
url = "http://example.com/main/index.php?code=hads1328fas&store=food#home";
url = url.replace(/code=[^&]+&/,'');
```

After this, url will contain

```
http://example.com/main/index.php?store=food#home
```