# How do I pass the Value from a Dropdown Form through a Link in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, parameter-passing

I have a dropdown select on my page called `language`, which is in a form with other elements. When the form is submitted normally (which submits everything), I can access the value of the dropdown with `params[:langauge]`.

I have another link/button on the page which, when clicked, should get the value of language and pass it to the controller. The controller could then run some ajax to change the language on the page. But how do I pass (just) the value of the dropdown through the link?

Update:
Should I get the value with Jquery, or is there a simpler way?

```
 $('select[name="language"]').val()
```

Comment: Value is one thing, construct url or change form hidden value is another thing. I think form should be simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This javascript code should update the URL whenever the dropdown value is changed.

```
$(function() {
$('#link-button').attr("href", "/link_path/" +$(this).val())
    $("select#language").change(function() {
        $('#link-button').attr("href", "/link_path/" +$(this).val())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If that is a link, the only way to use is query string

```
<a href="controller/method?lan=something">that link</a>
```

You can get "href" of that link by JS, and then use [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021027/1721198) to update query string.

Then the method will be able to process with correct params.

If that is a button, that would mean a mini form, you can set a hidden field inside the form and use jQuery to update its value. When sent, the controller method will know this value.

Comment: is there a simpler way? ie could i pass a parameter to the link which grabs the value of the dropdown? eg `link_to language_path("code to grab value")`

Comment: @am-rails, there may be simpler JS I just did not check it in depth. But you need to do that in JS instead of Ruby code, since the drowdown is supposed to change in client side.