# Dynamically load image with different GET parameters

Tags: php, jquery, html

I'm trying to load an image (created with PHP) with jQuery and passing a few variables with it (for example: `picture.php?user=1&type=2&color=64`). That's the easy part.

The hard part is that I've a dropdown which enables me to select background (the type parameter) and I'll have an input for example to select a color.

**Here're the problems I'm facing:**

1. If a dropdown/input hasn't been touched, I want to leave it out of the URL.
2. If a dropdown/input has been touched, I want to include it in the url. (This won't work by just adding a variable "`&type=2`" to the pre-existing string as if I touch the dropdown/input several times they'll stack (`&type=2&type=2&type=3`)).
3. When adding a variable ("`&type=2`" - see the code below) to the pre-existing URL, the &-sign disappears (it becomes like this: "`signature.php?user=1type=2`").

**Here's the code for the jQuery:**

```
<script>
    var url = "signatureload.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['sess_id']; ?>";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.setTimeout(LoadSignature, 1500);
    });

    $("#signature_type").change(function() {
        url += "&type="+$(this).val();

        LoadSignature();
    });

    function LoadSignature()
    {
        $("#loadingsignature").css("display", "block");
        $('#loadsignature').delay(4750).load(url, function() {
            $("#loadingsignature").css("display", "none");
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Here's the code where I load the image:**

```
<div id="loadsignature">
    <div id="loadingsignature" style="display: block;"><img src="img/loading-black.gif" alt="Loading.."></div>
</div>
```

I don't know how more further I could explain my problem. If you have any doubts or need more code, please let me know.

Thank you for your help!

**EDIT:**

Here's the current code:

```
<script>
    var url = "signatureload.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['sess_id']; ?>";

    $(document).ready(function() {

        window.setTimeout(LoadSignature, 1500);

    });

    $("#signature_type").change(function() {
        url = updateQueryStringParameter(url, 'type', $(this).val());

        LoadSignature();
    });

    function LoadSignature()
    {
        $("#loadingsignature").css("display", "block");
        $('#loadsignature').delay(4750).load(url, function() {
            $("#loadingsignature").css("display", "none");
        });
    }

    function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value)
    {
        var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i"),
        separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?",
        returnUri = '';

        if (uri.match(re))
        {
            returnUri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
        }
        else
        {
            returnUri = uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
        }

        return returnUri;
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT2:**

Here's the code for signatureload.php

```
<?php
    $url = "signature.php?";

    $count = 0;
    foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
    {
        if($count > 0) $url .= "&";
        $url .= "{$key}={$value}";
    }

    echo "<img src='{$url}'></img>";
?>
```

Comment: Still having issues? Still no & in the generated url? How do the current code look when generated? (that is not the server side code)

Comment: @NiKiZe @noam signatureload.php generates a <img> code with help from the parameters and here are the outputs from it after I've changed the select in the dropdown: `<img src="signature.php?user=1type=6">`

Comment: But this is the .php script, how does it look when you do view source in the browser? (I want to know where the & is lost, is it when the page is generated or is it something else when the javascript is executed)

Comment: It looks exactly like what I posted above. I guess it's when the javascript is executed or inside the php script. I've updated the question with the code in signatureload.php

Comment: Would it not be more effective to set the img src with jquery?
Other then that a `$count++;` in the foreach loop would probably fix this last issue of yours.

Comment: Oh my god, thank you soo much. How could I miss that one? It's always the small details which mess code up. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a variant where all the data is keept in a separate javascript array

```
<script>
    var baseurl = "signatureload.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['sess_id']; ?>";
    var urlparams = {};

    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.setTimeout(LoadSignature, 1500);
    });

    $("#signature_type").change(function() {
        urlparams['type'] = $(this).val();

        LoadSignature();
    });

    function LoadSignature()
    {
        var gurl = baseurl; // there is always a ? so don't care about that.
        for (key in urlparams) {
            gurl += '&' + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(urlparams[key]);
        }

        $("#loadingsignature").css("display", "block");
        $('#loadsignature').delay(4750).load(gurl, function() {
            $("#loadingsignature").css("display", "none");
        });
    }
</script>
```

With this color or any other parameter could be added with `urlparams['color'] = $(this).val();`

Comment: If this still do not generate & on the correct place try using "\u0026" instead of '&'. But in that case there is something more to this that is the root issue.

Comment: This was a really neat solution to the problem, thank you! The only problem left is the '&' which keeps dissappearing.

Comment: And you have also tested with `gurl += "\u0026" + encodeURIComponent(key) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(urlparams[key]);` instead ? (but please note that you should find the cause for why it disapears, even if it is out of scope of this question)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your question correctly, it comes down to finding a proper way of modifying GET parameters of the current URI using JavaScript/jQuery, right? As all the problems you point out come from changing the `type` parameter's value.

This is not trivial as it may seem though, there are even JavaScript plugins for this job. You could use a function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021027/2612112) and in your `signature_type` change event listener,

```
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i"),
        separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?",
        returnUri = '';

    if (uri.match(re)) {
        returnUri = uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
    } else {
        returnUri = uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
    }

    return returnUri;
}

$('#signature_type').change(function () {

    // Update the type param using said function
    url = updateQueryStringParameter(url, 'type', $(this).val());

    LoadSignature();
});
```

Comment: It won't create the parameter if it doesn't exist, will it?

Comment: @MagnusBurton Yes, it will. If it doesn't exist it will create it. If it does, it will just change it's value.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it's setting the url variable to the variable with the added parameter. Therefore, I modified it abit and now it still won't add the *&*-sign:

url = updateQueryStringParameter(url, 'type', $(this).val());

Comment: @MagnusBurton Yes, I forgot to assign the value to the url variable. Also, I think the function had some errors. Check if it works with the updated version.

Comment: I appreciate your help but the & still doesn't show up. Am I doing something weird or? Updated the question with what my current code looks like.

Comment: @MagnusBurton Hmm that is strange. It is working for me http://jsfiddle.net/Jp68X/1/.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36282/discussion-between-magnus-burton-and-campari)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try storing your selected value in a variable, and then using AJAX post data and load image. That way you ensure there is only one variable, not repeating ones. Here's example

```
var type= 'default_value';

    $("#signature_type").change(function() {        
        type = $(this).val();
    });
```

then using ajax call it like this (you could do this in your "change" event function):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url:    'signatureload.php', 
    data: {
        user: <?php echo $_SESSION['sess_id']; ?>,
        type: type,
        ... put other variables here ...
    },
    success: function(answer){ 
        //load image to div here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
<script>
    var baseUrl = "signatureload.php?user=<?php echo $_SESSION['sess_id']; ?>";

    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            LoadSignature(baseUrl);
        }, 1500);
    });

    $("#signature_type").change(function() {
        var urlWithSelectedType = baseUrl + "&type="+$(this).val();
        LoadSignature(urlWithSelectedType);
    });

    function LoadSignature(urlToLoad)
    {
        $("#loadingsignature").css("display", "block");
        $('#loadsignature').delay(4750).load(urlToLoad, function() {
            $("#loadingsignature").css("display", "none");
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: It would work but upon change it'd just add another *&type=* to the url instead of replacing the current one.

Comment: Actually you wouldn't be adding/appending another &type= because you are not changing the baseUrl, the LoadSignature function will always receive a clean url that is the baseUrl plus the &type=, there is no accumulating concatenation.

Comment: Oh okay, sorry then. Javascript isn't my top language as you might notice. I've tried your solution and the '&'-sign keeps dissappearing.

Comment: That's strange, maybe there is something in the sess_id? can you post an example baseUrl

Comment: Are you setting `$_SESSION['sess_id']` somewhere in your code?