# Form Get function without a form

Tags: javascript, html, forms, web

Is there a way to use a function similar to a html forms 'get' function to append a url based on the text of a textbox when a button is pressed without using a form?

```
    <form method="get" action="https://www.google.co.uk/">
    <input type="text" name="q"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

I don't think I can use a normal form for this because I want to have 1 textbox but two functions and two buttons (Google Search and Bing Search). If I am wrong please feel free to tell me how to add two functions to one form!

Comment: possible duplicate of [add or update query string parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter)

Comment: Way too advanced for me! I am looking for something really simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular buttons instead of submit buttons, and wire them to change the form's action before submitting:

```
<form method="get" action="https://www.google.co.uk/">
  <input type="text" name="q"/>
  <input type="button" value="Google Search" onClick="this.form.action='https://www.google.co.uk'; this.form.submit();"/>
  <input type="button" value="Bing Search" onClick="this.form.action='https://www.bing.co.uk'; this.form.submit();"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Solved problem perfectly. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

Something Like this might get you in the right direction?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  <input type="text" value="Value of First Text Box" id="box1">
  <input type="text" value="Value of Second Text Box" id="box2">

  <script>
  (function() {
  var x  = document.getElementById('box1').value;
  var y  = document.getElementById('box2').value;


  alert(document.location +'?'+ x + '?' + y);
  })();
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

**http://plnkr.co/edit/ZEso7gtHyCW241O0E59w?p=preview**

But you should Ideally look at the answer posted in question comment.