# Greasemonkey script to add parameter to URL

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm not good at JS so I've been toying around with some Greasemonkey scripts I've managed to find, but they didn't perform as expected. What I want is very basic:

Check if the URL within a domain contains the variable `lang` - either `?lang` or `&lang`

If the URL contains that variable, check its value: If the value is `en` do nothing, if however the value is anything else, replace it with `en`

If the URL doesn't contain the variable `lang` add it to the end of the URL, as in `&lang=en`

Any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    var url = document.location.toString();
    var updateUrl = updateQueryStringParameter(url, 'lang', 'en');
    console.log(updateUrl);
    console.log(url != updateUrl);
    if (url != updateUrl) {
        document.location = updateUrl;
    }
} catch (e) {}

function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
    var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
    var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
    if (uri.match(re)) {
        return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
    } else {
        return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location). `.search` contains the query in a string.

```
// if the query doesn't contain lang=en
if (!window.location.search.match(/[?&]lang=en(&|$)/)) {
  // either replace an existing lang=... param or append it
  window.location.search = window.location.search.
    replace(/[?&]lang=[^&]*|$/, '&lang=en');
}
```

Comment: This works, but in case the URL is domain.com/?lang=xx it will replace it with domain.com/?&lang=xx - i.e. add & to the ?. Thank you for taking the time and helping me!