# jQuery - Automatically add query string parameter

Tags: jquery, url, query-string

I need a script that automatically adds to **all** pages on my website the `ffv` query string parameter, as in the following examples:

```
mywebsite.com?ffv

mywebsite.com/page?ffv

mywebsite.com/basket?ffv
```

Comment: When you say 'all urls' do you mean those in `a` elements only, or is this including the `action` attribute on `form` elements, and `background-images` etc?

Comment: I mean physical pages, not page elements

Comment: @gdjc To make it very simple: you mean the urls in the url bar in the browser, right? You want them to have automatically "?ffv" attached, right?

Comment: @clami219 - Yes, all URLs in the browser bar to have the aforementioned string attached to them.

Answer (score 0):

The url is - https://mywebsite.com/path?ffv#hash

```
http[s]:// - protocol <br>
mywebsite.com - domain <br>
/path - path <br> 
?ffv - query string <br>
\#value - hash
```

if you need to change query string, try JavaScript `window.location` object 
for change query:

```
function replace_search(value) {

    "use strict";

    if (typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number') {
        window.location.search = value;
    }

}
```

on page side u cat use onclick event for manual change:

```
    <button onclick="replace_search('query')">got to query</button>
```

Comment: That puts the page in to an eternal looping refresh though?

Comment: create function for change and execute it if u need

Comment: Nope not working. 

Another option is to change the URL:

At present it has: /p/

Change it to /product/

I'm trying to drop a cookie so that I can run a fairly large A/B test (the _ff=v is the cookie)

Comment: /p/ - its pathname attr, if u wanna change it - use window.location.pathname

Comment: Have you got a code example? Am not exactly a master in jQuery or JavaScript

Comment: function replace_path(value) {

    "use strict";

    if (typeof value === 'string' || typeof value === 'number') {
        window.location.path = value;
    }

}

Answer (score 0):

Using the solutions presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript#3855394) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter#6021027) (with a slight adaptation), you can get the query string values and change them.

Starting from that, you can use the following code to do what you need:

```
//This allows you to read the query string
(function($) {
    $.QueryString = (function(a) {
        if (a == "") return {};
        var b = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
        {
            var p=a[i].split('=');
            if (p.length != 2) continue;
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        return b;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);

(function(){
    //This allows you to set the query string parameters
    function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
        var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
        var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
        if (uri.match(re)) {
            return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + ( (value !=  '' ) ? "=" + value : "") + '$2');
        }
        else {
            return uri + separator + key + ( (value !=  '' ) ? "=" + value : "");
        }
    }

    // When you load the page, you check if the query string doesn't contain "ffv"
    if(typeof $.QueryString["ffv"] == "undefined") {
        //If it doesn't, you add it
        window.location.href = updateQueryStringParameter(window.location.href,'ffv','');
    }
})();
```

You need to check if `ffv` is set before adding it, in order to avoid a loop.