# Run JQuery Functions

Tags: jquery

I have a .js file that I am trying to merge with my current website. It is designed to where after a set amount of time, a dialog is shown to the user with the option to either log out now, or stay connected. I acquired the .js file online and cannot seem to understand the directions for its usage. The directions are as follows

// USAGE

1. Include jQuery
2. Include jQuery UI (for dialog)
3. Include jquery.sessionTimeout.js
4. Call $.sessionTimeout(); after document ready

here is the jquery.sessionTimeout.js with documentation.

```
/*jshint browser:true*/

//
// jquery.sessionTimeout.js
//
// After a set amount of time, a dialog is shown to the user with the option
// to either log out now, or stay connected. If log out now is selected,
// the page is redirected to a logout URL. If stay connected is selected,
// a keep-alive URL is requested through AJAX. If no options is selected
// after another set amount of time, the page is automatically redirected
// to a timeout URL.
//
//
// USAGE
//
//   1. Include jQuery
//   2. Include jQuery UI (for dialog)
//   3. Include jquery.sessionTimeout.js
//   4. Call $.sessionTimeout(); after document ready
//
//
// OPTIONS
//
//   message
//     Text shown to user in dialog after warning period.
//     Default: 'Your session is about to expire.'
//
//   keepAliveUrl
//     URL to call through AJAX to keep session alive. This resource should    do something innocuous that would keep the session alive, which will depend on your server-side platform.
//     Default: '/keep-alive'
//
//   keepAliveAjaxRequestType
//     How should we make the call to the keep-alive url? (GET/POST/PUT)
//     Default: 'POST'
//
//   redirUrl
//     URL to take browser to if no action is take after warning period
//     Default: '/timed-out'
//
//   logoutUrl
//     URL to take browser to if user clicks "Log Out Now"
//     Default: '/log-out'
//
//   warnAfter
//     Time in milliseconds after page is opened until warning dialog is opened
//     Default: 900000 (15 minutes)
//
//   redirAfter
//     Time in milliseconds after page is opened until browser is redirected to redirUrl
//     Default: 1200000 (20 minutes)
//
//   appendTime
//     If true, appends the current time stamp to the Keep Alive url to prevent caching issues
//     Default: true
//
(function ($) {
    jQuery.sessionTimeout = function (options) {
        var defaults = {
            message: 'Your session is about to expire.',
            keepAliveUrl: '/keep-alive',
            keepAliveAjaxRequestType: 'POST',
            redirUrl: '/timed-out',
            logoutUrl: '/log-out',
            warnAfter: 900000, // 15 minutes
            redirAfter: 1200000, // 20 minutes
            appendTime: true // appends time stamp to keep alive url to prevent caching
        };

    // Extend user-set options over defaults
    var o = defaults,
            dialogTimer,
            redirTimer;

    if (options) { o = $.extend(defaults, options); }

    // Create timeout warning dialog
    $('body').append('<div title="Session Timeout" id="sessionTimeout-dialog">' + o.message + '</div>');
    $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        open: function () { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); },
        buttons: {
            // Button one - takes user to logout URL
            "Log Out Now": function () {
                window.location = o.logoutUrl;
            },
            // Button two - closes dialog and makes call to keep-alive URL
            "Stay Connected": function () {
                $(this).dialog('close');

                $.ajax({
                    type: o.keepAliveAjaxRequestType,
                    url: o.appendTime ? updateQueryStringParameter(o.keepAliveUrl, "_", new Date().getTime()) : o.keepAliveUrl
                });

                // Stop redirect timer and restart warning timer
                controlRedirTimer('stop');
                controlDialogTimer('start');
            }
        }
    });

    function controlDialogTimer(action) {
        switch (action) {
            case 'start':
                // After warning period, show dialog and start redirect timer
                dialogTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    $('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog('open');
                    controlRedirTimer('start');
                }, o.warnAfter);
                break;

            case 'stop':
                clearTimeout(dialogTimer);
                break;
        }
    }

    function controlRedirTimer(action) {
        switch (action) {
            case 'start':
                // Dialog has been shown, if no action taken during redir period, redirect
                redirTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                    window.location = o.redirUrl;
                }, o.redirAfter - o.warnAfter);
                break;

            case 'stop':
                clearTimeout(redirTimer);
                break;
        }
    }

    // Courtesy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter
    // Includes fix for angular ui-router as per comment by j_walker_dev
    function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
        var re = new RegExp("([?|&])" + key + "=.*?(&|#|$)", "i");

        if (uri.match(re)) {
            return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
        } else {
            var hash = '';

            if (uri.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
                hash = uri.replace(/.*#/, '#');
                uri = uri.replace(/#.*/, '');
            }

            var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
            return uri + separator + key + "=" + value + hash;
        }
    }

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        if (!$('#sessionTimeout-dialog').dialog("isOpen")) {
            controlRedirTimer('stop');
            controlDialogTimer('stop');
            controlDialogTimer('start');
        }
    });

    // Begin warning period
    controlDialogTimer('start');
};
})(jQuery);
```

I am still new to JQuery and don't quit understand how to go about implementing it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What part(s) don't you understand?

Comment: I'd echo @j08691. Directions seem straightforward. You need to explain what your gaps are.

Comment: Did you include the required libraries and the function call as mentioned in the usage directions?

Comment: I don't really understand any of it. I've only dealt with HTML, CSS, PHP, and Javascript. I've never used JQuery before so I'm unsure what all I need to do to my HTML file to make it work.

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, especially if you're already familiar with HTML and JavaScript. Link three files and call the plugin. They have examples on the project's page so you should be able to handle this.

Comment: I thought it was simple enough but I knew I was missing something and Marc cleared it up for me and now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like this in the `<HEAD>` of your document:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="sessionTimeout.js"></script>
<script>
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
    $.sessionTimeout();
});
</script>
```

That's using the Google CDN for jQuery components, and it assumes your `sessionTimeout.js` file is in the same location as your HTML file.

You could place the scripts elsewhere, e.g. near the bottom of the HTML, but that's for another discussion.  Putting it in `HEAD` is the simple way.

Comment: Thank you, I was wondering what exactly it was that I needed to add.  All I knew was to add the                                        <script src="sessionTimeout.js"></script> but not the other stuff. Much appreciated

Comment: Can you approve the answer?