# Replace url parameter dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that adds the value from a clicked element. However - I would like to replace the value with the new one when clicked.

Example:

```
<ul class="acfilter">
 <li><a href="reset">reset</a></li>
 <li><a href="One">One</a></li>
 <li><a href="Two">Two</a></li>
</ul>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.acfilter li a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).attr('href') != "reset") {
            if (location.href.indexOf('?') === -1) {
                location.href = location.href + "?fss=" + $(this).attr('href');
            } else {
                location.href = location.href + "+" + $(this).attr('href');
            }
        } else {
            location.href = location.origin + location.pathname;
        }
    });
});
```

First parameter onclick gives `?fss=one` and on the second click you get ?`fss=one+two`. The reset link clears it.

However - I would like to replace the "one" value with the "two" value on the click. The value is dynamic - so I cant just do If/Else url.replace with the known value.

How do I do this?

Edit:

Forgot to mention that there can be other parameters in the url. Example:

First click gives

```
?fss=one
```

and the when doing an action that gives the other parameter I mention it gives this:

```
?param=list&fss=one
```

which is correct by using the script from user brijesh chowdary lavu. The param=list is a parameter that always has to be first, and is written to do so and changes from list to largelist, this also works with that script.

Problem is when I click on my specific class a second time - instead of going from

```
?param=list&fss=one
```

to

```
?param=list&fss=two
```

it replaces everything to

```
?fss=one
```

Comment: try these anwers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 $('ul.acfilter li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('href') != "reset") {
        if (location.href.indexOf('?') === -1) {
            location.href = location.href + "?fss=" + $(this).attr('href');
        } else {
            location.href = location.origin + location.pathname + "?fss=" + $(this).attr('href');
        }
    } else {
        location.href = location.origin + location.pathname;
    }
});
```

Or with simple string methods, you can add a function to your script like below, so that other parameters don't have to change:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('ul.acfilter li a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if ($(this).attr('href') != "reset") {
        if (location.href.indexOf('?') === -1) {
            location.href = location.href + "?fss=" + $(this).attr('href');
        } else {
            location.href = changeParameter(window.location.toString(),"fss",$(this).attr('href'));
        }
    } else {
        location.href = location.origin + location.pathname;
    }
});

});
     function changeParameter(str,par,val)
    {
            var t1 = str.indexOf(par);
            var t3 = t1+par.length+1;
            var t2= str.indexOf("&",t3);
            if(t2==-1)
            {
                return str.substring(0,t3)+val;
            }
            else
            {
                return str.substring(0,t3)+val+str.substring(t2);
            }
    }
```

Comment: well, maybe, but certainly not a general solution as it wouldn't work if he had ?fss=one&foo=bar

Comment: This works - but fails if I have another parameter in the url - it then replaces that one too instead of adding it - i only want to replace the value from the specified class. Maybe should have mention that this could be the case.

Comment: Hmm the second part don't seems to work - it gave me an url of /httone when another parameter was present.

Comment: A semicolon was missing, try now !

Comment: Strange, it still gives the same result

Answer (score 0):

You need to track your parameter `fss` (not the value) and replace the value of it all the time.

The best way to do this is by `split` from the point of `fss`.

```
//Lets split the href by the param fss
var urlParts = location.href.split("fss");

//Insert your new value together with the param. (split removes the param)
if (location.href.indexOf("?") < 0) 
   location.href = urlParts[0] + "?fss=" + $(this).attr('href');
else    
   location.href = urlParts[0] + "fss=" + $(this).attr('href');
```

And for resetting

```
location.href = location.href.split("fss")[0];
```

Comment: Hi Charlie and thanks for the reply. However - I dont seems to be able to get this working, would you be kind do show me how to write it to work with my reset option?

Comment: Sorry - there was a mistake. Answer updated. `split` creates an array out of the parts of the string sans the delimiter (fss). Thats the theory here.