# Update parameter on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a script that adds a parameter to the url on a click - and replaces the the parameter with another on the second click. This works great.

However there is a scenario when there already is a parameter in place - and I then need this click to replace that value.

Example:

Click one gives

```
?param=largegrid
```

Second one replaces the value and gives

```
?param=smallgrid
```

But sometimes the url looks like this:

```
?param=grid or param=grid&fss=tablet
```

in this case i want the click to replace the first value so the url looks like

```
?param=large or param=largegrid&fss=tablet
```

and the same for the second click.

```
$('.click10').on('click', function() {
console.log("Clicked");
var url = window.location.pathname;
var url = window.location.href;
if (url.indexOf('?param=largegrid') > -1) {
url = url.replace("?param=largegrid", "") + '?param=smallgrid'
} else {
url = url.replace("?param=smallgrid", "") + '?param=largegrid'
}
window.location.href = url;
});
```

Comment: Have look at [add or update query string parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter)

Comment: You could split the URL then apply your logic to each piece then rebuild it again

Comment: Hmm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Will look at the link, thanks.

Comment: link provided by Satpal is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, search for the param of either grid or large-grid and next you can replace them alternatively.

```js
if (url.indexOf('?param=grid') > -1) {
url = url.replace("grid", "") + 'largegrid'
} else if(url.indexOf('largegrid') > -1) {
url = url.replace("largegrid", "") + 'smallgrid'
} else if(url.indexOf('smallgrid') > -1) {
url = url.replace("smallgrid", "") + 'largegrid'
}
```

Comment: That worked but only for largegrid - it removed the smallgrid functionality.

Comment: In the third point you have mentioned, you mentioned about grid and large grid.When you need small grid?

Comment: Hmm. Its close! the problem now is that the buttons i have for smallgrid and largegrid doesn't work if there is no parameter - they only work if =grid is in the url. Almost!

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, please do accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex for that like

```
url= url.replace(/(largegrid=)[^\&]+/,updated_largegrid);
```

---

### Update

Okay what you can do is(as per your posted code) :

- Have the onclick function
- Inside that use `var url = window.location.href;`
- Now replace all the variables like  `url= url.replace(/(largegrid=)[^\&]+/,updated_largegrid);`
- You are good to go now

Comment: Hi Tushar - do I add or replace a part of my code with the regex? My script skills aren't that good, unfortunaly :)

Comment: @user3344734 Updated \m/

Comment: Hmm. tried this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMQKMy but that script didnt work. What did i miss there? Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend to library [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/). It helps parsing and building URIs/URLs. For example, you don't need to worry if the query parameter already exists:

For example, both

```
var newURL = URI("http://www.example.com/").setQuery("param", "smallgrid").toString();
```

and

```
var newURL = URI("http://www.example.com/?param=largegrid").setQuery("param", "smallgrid").toString();
```

both result in `http://www.example.com/?param=smallgrid`

An example for your event handler using a callback:

```
$('.click10').on('click', function() {
  var url = window.location.href;

  url = URI(url).search(function(queryData) {
      queryData.param = (queryData.param === "largegrid") ? "smallgrid" : "largegrid";
  });

  window.location.href = url;
});
```