# replace anchor tag href with variable from url string javascript

Tags: javascript

I have following java script code:

```
var product = getQueryVariable("product");

$('a.link').each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href") + "&product=" + getQueryVariable("product"));
});

function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);        

    var variables = query.split("&");

    for (var iCount = 0; iCount < variables.length; iCount++)
    {
        var pair = variables[iCount].split("=");

        if (pair[0] == variable)
            return pair[1];
    }
}
```

If url is: `http://www.xxxx.com/index.htm?product=abc`, It sets a link to an anchor tag

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.aaaa.com/index.htm">Click here</a>
```

as

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.aaaa.com/index.htm?product=abc">Click here</a>
```

which is what I want, and it does it well.

But if anchor tag already has `product` variable in its `href` like

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.aaaa.com/index.htm?product=xyz">Click here</a>
```

then I get

```
<a class="link" href="http://www.aaaa.com/index.htm?product=xyz&product=abc">Click here</a>
```

while I was expecting that if `product` variable is present in `href` of anchor tag, it will replace existing product variable. And if there is no product variable in `href` tag, it will append it.

The code appends well, but does not replace existing `product` variable in `href` of anchor tag.

So, the question is how do I get `'product'` param from all `a` tags that have class `'link'`? so that I can replace it in my code if found. And can I fetch it in `$('a.link').each(function()` ?

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [add or update query string parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter)

Comment: a good solution to this is ... get all your params from url and then all params from your `a` tag links and then remove the duplicates and then form a new query string.

Comment: @LostMyGlasses thanks for quick reply. My page is at: http://products.softsolutionslimited.com/img2ocr/register1.htm?product=jpg2word I already have added https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js in it. what should be the new code?

Comment: @HarryBomrah thanks for quick reply. My page is at: http://products.softsolutionslimited.com/img2ocr/register1.htm?product=jpg2word I already have added ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js in it. what should be the new code?

Comment: @ComputerUser do u want to change all the links in this page?

Comment: @HarryBomrah no, there is "Click here" hyperlink in the page http://products.softsolutionslimited.com/img2ocr/register1.htm?product=jpg2word . That 'click here' of anchor tag takes user to the payment page and must forward the same product from the url. Please see "Click here" hyperlink in page http://products.softsolutionslimited.com/img2ocr/register1.htm?product=jpg2word

Comment: @HarryBomrah how do I get 'product' param from all a tags that have class 'link'? so that I can replace it in my code if found. And can I fetch it in $('a.link').each(function() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked:

```
$('a.link').each(function()
{
    var anchor_url = $(this).attr("href");
    var product_val = '';

    if (-1 == anchor_url.indexOf('&product='))
    {
        if (-1 == anchor_url.indexOf('?product='))
            product_val = anchor_url.substr(anchor_url.indexOf('?product=')+'?product='.length);
    }
    else
        product_val = anchor_url.substr(anchor_url.indexOf('&product=')+'&product='.length);

    if (product_val.indexOf('&') != -1) product_val = product_val.substr(0, product_val.indexOf('&'))

    if (product_val == '') new_link = anchor_url+'&product='+getQueryVariable("product");
    else new_link = anchor_url.split(product_val).join(getQueryVariable("product"));

    $(this).attr("href",  new_link);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
function changeLinkQueries(link,parameter,replacedVal) {

  // This function is anonymous, is executed immediately and 
  // the return value is assigned to QueryString!
  var query_string = {};
  var query = link.split('?')[1];
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
     var pair = vars[i].split("=");
     // If first entry with this name
     if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
       query_string[pair[0]] = decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
       // If second entry with this name
     } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
       var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]],decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) ];
       query_string[pair[0]] = arr;
       // If third or later entry with this name
     } else {
       query_string[pair[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(pair[1]));
     }
  } 

  var queries = query_string,
    linkArr = [];
  queries[parameter] = replacedVal;

  for(query in queries){
    linkArr.push(query + '=' + queries[query]);
  }

  return link.split('?')[0] + '?' + linkArr.join('&');

};
```

The function usage is : `changeLinkQueries(link,parameter,replacedVal)`:

- link : is the link that you want to modify
- parameter: the parameter you want to change
- replacedVal: the value that you want to replace with it

**Example:** `changeLinkQueries('http://www.aaaa.com/index.htm?product=xyz','product','test')` returns ==> http://www.aaaa.com/index.htm?product=test

Add this function to your code and update your code to :

```
var product = getQueryVariable("product");

$('a.link').each(function(){
    $(this).attr("href", changeLinkQueries($(this).attr("href"),'product',getQueryVariable('product')));
});

function getQueryVariable(variable)
{
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);        

    var variables = query.split("&");

    for (var iCount = 0; iCount < variables.length; iCount++)
    {
        var pair = variables[iCount].split("=");

        if (pair[0] == variable)
            return pair[1];
    }
}
```

Comment: first of all this will not work if the url has product anywhere. Plus OP wants to replace the value of product if found not keep as it is. your code will just return the same link without modifying product value

Comment: Please check my answer and test it, I believe it's the best one and easiest to implement

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
Array.prototype.contains = function(x){
  return this.indexOf( x ) > -1 ? true : false;
}

var getUrlVars = function(url){
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = url.slice(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++){
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(decodeURIComponent(hash[0]));
        vars[decodeURIComponent(hash[0])] = decodeURIComponent(hash[1]);
     }
     if(vars[0] == url){
        vars =[];
     }
     return vars;
}


var getUrl = function(url){
    var urlParams = getUrlVars(window.location.href),
        linkParams = getUrlVars(url),
        altered = false;

    for(i = 0; i < linkParams.length; i++){
        var t = linkParams[i];
        if(urlParams.contains(t)){
            linkParams[t] = urlParams[t];
            altered = true;
        }
    }
    return altered ? url.split("?")[0] + "?" + linkParams.map(function(y){return y + "=" + linkParams[y]}).join("&") : url;
}

$("a.link").each(function (i,link) {
    link.attr("href",getUrl(link.attr("href")));
})
```

Comment: thanks. I am trying now. I will post results in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('a.link').each(function()
{
    $(this).attr("href", $(this).attr("href").split("product=")[0] + "product=" + getQueryVariable("product"));
});

This works with links already containing product value
```

Comment: trying now. I will post results.

Comment: It gave me href like: http://www.aaaa.com/index.htm?&product=jpg2word  notice ?& in url. Is this good?

Comment: sorry added that & by mistake when i copied your code. Check now. I have modified my answer. There won't be & in link.

Answer (score -1):

i hope this will help,

```
$(this).attr("href", getQueryVariable($(this).attr("href"), "product"));

function getQueryVariable(hrefLink, variable)
{
    if(hrefLink.contains("product")){
        return hrefLink;
    }else{
        //write your code here and return full url

    }
}
```

Comment: first of all this will not work if the url has product  anywhere. Plus OP wants to replace the value of product if found not keep as it is. your code will just return the same link without modifying `product` value

Comment: this will also give you true `var x = "http://www.softsolutionslimited.com/products/purchase.test.php"; x.contains("product"); // true` This is the same link from your click here link, just removed the params.