# iframe src add autoplay=true parameter onclick with existing value

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="//player.net/14965165444001/default_default/index.html?videoId=4784345556001" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>

<button>click</button>
```

On iframe src, when clicked the "button".. it have to add "?autoplay=true" with the present src value.

Like this I add 5 elements inside the slider.

Comment: Refer this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6021027/1746830

Answer (score 1):

Set the `src` of the `iframe` using `.attr` method

[`updateQueryStringParameter`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6021027/1746830) function is referred from [*amateur*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/373674/amateur)

```js
function updateQueryStringParameter(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  } else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}

$('#update').on('click', function() {
  var url = $('#iframe').attr('src');
  var Updatedurl = updateQueryStringParameter(url, 'autoplay', 'true');
  $('#iframe').attr('src', Updatedurl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<iframe id="iframe" src="//player.net/14965165444001/default_default/index.html?videoId=4784345556001" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe>

<button id='update'>click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var iframe = $('#iframe');
var src = iframe.attr('src');
$('button').click(function() {
  if (src.indexOf('autoplay=true') !== -1) {
    iframe.attr('src', src + '&autoplay=true');
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. But, it possible to block adding "&autoplay=true" if already exists in the src?

Comment: I changed the answer to look for `autoplay=true` first.