# Can I set a request parameter in the HTTP request by using a javascript

Tags: javascript

I know it is most basic question to ask but I am struggling to get the answer for this.

I have a scenario where I need to modify a Query Parameter of a HTTP Get request that was triggered  when an user clicked on a link(Anchor tag) from browser using Java script.is it possible?

Comment: Possible connection with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter

Answer (score 0):

1. [Bind an event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to the link.
2. [Use `preventDefault` to cancel the normal behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) so the link isn't followed.
3. Read `href` to get the destination.
4. [Modify the query string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter) (e.g. with `String.prototype.replace`)
5. Assign the result [to `location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: Thanks for reply Quentin.Here I need to get the http get request url when an user performs an action from the browser UI such as clicking on an link or button and add a new Query parameter to it.How to get that url?