# HTML link increase querystring value by 1

Tags: append, query-string

I have www.example.com/profile?listingID=20

I want to create two buttons (Next & Previous) that would just add or subtract from the (ListingID Value) in the current query-string.

Basically just to create next/prev buttons to pull up the next row in my table as i'm using that parameter to pull everything.

I don't know if this would be done in java-script? Any examples appreciated.

Comment: it's easier to do it with server side language.. just do GET request and increment/decrement value by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `Javascript` and specifically `window.location.search`....here you can see different approaches [add or update query string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/add-or-update-query-string-parameter)