# Keep params while navigating through routes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

How can I keep params while navigating through routes. The parameter/parameters have to be in every page of the application (not only in nested routes). In angular I can do this with `this._router.navigate([''], { queryParamsHandling: 'merge' })`, but how can I do it with vue.js?

Example of base routes:

```
// base route 1 -> http://example.test/?user_code=1234&member=false
// base route 2 -> http://example.test/?user_code=56789&member=false
// base route 3 -> http://example.test/?user_code=4321
```

How can I keep the parameters `user_code` and `member` in every route I navigate?

Example of what I want

```
// navigated route 1 -> http://example.test/about?user_code=1234&member=false
// navigated route 2 -> http://example.test/whatever_page?user_code=56789&member=false
// ...
```

Why I need this? Because then I will need the params to do things in the app `Ex: this.$route.query.user_code == '1234' ? 'do this' : 'do that';`

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A typical approach would be to use state and push the fullPath of the route into that state attribute (likely an Array).

With vuex:

```
// store/index.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    paths: []
  },
  mutations: {
    PUSH_PATH (fullPath) {
      paths.push(fullPath)
    }
  },
  actions: {
    pushPath(commit, fullPath) {
       commit("PUSH_PATH", fullPath)  
    }
  } 
})
```

```
// in a component
import { mapActions } from "vuex";
...

  methods: {
    ...mapActions("pushPath")
  },
  created() {
    this.pushPath(this.$route.fullPath)
  }
```

Now if you used pushPath, when your view is created, it would add the fullPath to an array that you could later make decisions about either through injection, inspection, etc.

Another popular option, especially when making decisions based on routes is to use "Navigation Guards". These are functions that intercept the route and allow you to perform some action. More details are available here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: I ended up by using the 2 solutions provided by you. After setting everything in the store, I then injected the route with beforeEach guards. Got some inspiration in the reply of @CenterOrbit (user:663058) here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42226479/how-to-hold-url-query-params-in-vue-with-vue-router

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple examples of using a navigation guard to persist query params.  To use this technique to preserve a single `foo` parameter:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  if ('foo' in from.query && !('foo' in to.query)) {
    return { ...to, query: { ...to.query, foo: from.query.foo } };
  }
  return true;
});
```

To copy over everything that is in `from` but not in `to`:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
  const missing = Object.entries(from.query).filter(([k]) => !(k in to.query));
  if (missing.length > 0) {
    return { ...to, query: { ...to.query, ...Object.fromEntries(missing) } };
  }
  return true;
});
```