# How to pass a value returned by Javascript function to a url in django?

Tags: javascript, django, google-places-api

I am using Google Place Autocomplete in django template. I have a search bar which will show prediction for places. When users clicks the search button, I want to pass the value which is in search bar to django URL.

Below is the code

```
<label for="locationTextField">Location</label>
<input id="locationTextField" type="text" size="50">

<a href="{% url 'filteredcars' city  %}" id= "output">Search</a> 

<script>
    function init() {
        var input = document.getElementById('locationTextField');
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function f1() {
            var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
            var city = place.address_components[0].short_name;
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = city;
        });
     }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);
</script>
```

I am able to get the *city* and show it in a HTML page, but I am not able to pass it as parameter in URL.

Can someone please give me any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having a different URL for each city (i.e `/url/to/city1`, `/url/to/city2` etc) a much better approach is to have a single URL (i.e `/url/to/city`) and pass the `city` as a `GET` parameter (i.e `/url/to/city/?name=city1`). Do not let the `GET` (`?` character) discourage you. It is perfectly valid and quite self-explanatory (i.e when the resource `/url/to/city` is given a `GET` parameter - city name -, say `amsterdam`, it will serve a page with that city).

Enough with the theory, let's dive into code.

The `a`'s `href` attribute will be:

```
<a href="{% url 'filteredcars' %}" id= "output">Search</a>
```

Inside `script` and **above** `init()` insert this handy function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter/6021027#6021027)):

```
function updateQueryStringParam(uri, key, value) {
  var re = new RegExp("([?&])" + key + "=.*?(&|$)", "i");
  var separator = uri.indexOf('?') !== -1 ? "&" : "?";
  if (uri.match(re)) {
    return uri.replace(re, '$1' + key + "=" + value + '$2');
  }
  else {
    return uri + separator + key + "=" + value;
  }
}
```

and then **below** `var city = ...`, insert:

```
output = document.getElementById("output");
output.href = updateQueryStringParam(output.href, 'name', city);
output.innerHTML = city;
```

Now, each time the event `place_changed` is triggered, the `href` will be updated to this format: `/url/to/city/?name=<value_entered>`

By doing this, you need to update the relevant code inside both `urls.py` and `views.py` files to handle the extra `GET` parameter (not too much to change, though ;). Share you code, if you don't know how.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. I figured out changes in urls.py and views.py.