# jQuery redirect to specific URL based on checkbox click category

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, mysqli

I have an multiple category on my page to filter search.

```
http://localhost/shop/category/produkunggulan/CT0002
```

Example I have this category:

Brand

```
$qBrandList = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT P.productid, P.brandid_fk, B.Brandid, B.brand_name FROM tb_product P, tb_brand B WHERE P.brandid_fk = B.brandid AND P.categoryid_fk LIKE '%" . $getCategoryID . "%' GROUP BY B.brandid ORDER BY B.brand_name ASC");
while($dBrandList = mysqli_fetch_array($qBrandList))
{
?>
    <div><label><input name="chkBrand[]" class="chkBrand" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $dBrandList['brandid_fk']; ?>"/> <?php echo $dBrandList['brand_name']; ?></label></div>
<?php
}
```

Discount

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="discount" value="Y"/> Diskon</label>
```

Now I want when user click the checkbox, it will be directly redirect to the url including the key of category (every click checkbox) and remove the value if uncheck.

Example I click EMORI then FOSSIL, so the URL should be:

```
http://localhost/shop/category/produkunggulan/CT0002?brand=BR0003,BR0010
```

[image]

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter#6021027

Comment: @MustacheMoses how to call the function?

Comment: The function is JavaScript not PHP. You will need javascript on the client side to add and remove items from the query string.

Answer (score 1):

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="discount" value="Y"/> Diskon</label>
```

I don't think you need to use a checkbox to redirect. Simply use input type 'submit'.

```
<label><input type="submit" name="discount" value="Diskon"/>
```

or add onchange event to submit

```
<label><input type="checkbox" onChange="this.form.submit()" name="discount" value="Y"/> Diskon</label>
```

also use 'get' method in the  tag to show your data at url.

One thing for sure your url wont look as you mentioned rather that it will look as

```
http://localhost/shop/category/produkunggulan/CT0002?chkBrand%5B%5D=BR0003& chkBrand%5B%5D=BR0010
```

Here %5B is for'[' and %5D is for ']'.