# jQuery get categoryid from filter search on URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, url

Continue on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709658/jquery-redirect-to-specific-url-based-on-checkbox-click-category/49710063#49710063)

Now I would like to get `categoryid` from this below URL:

```
                                              categoryid
http://localhost/badar/category/produkterbaru/CT0007?brand=BR0006,BR0010
```

Category ID is `CT0007`

Here is the JS

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (e) {
      var data = {},
          fdata = [],
          loc = $('<a>', { href: window.location })[0];
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function (i) {
          if (this.checked) {
              if (!data.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
                  data[this.name] = [];
              }
              data[this.name].push(this.value);
          }
      });

      // get all keys.
      var keys = Object.keys(data);
      var fdata = "";
      // iterate over them and create the fdata
      keys.forEach(function(key,i){
          if (i>0) fdata += '&'; // if its not the first key add &
          fdata += key+"="+data[key].join(',');
      });

      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "<?php echo $appURL; ?>/productByCategory",
        data: {
              "fdata": fdata
            },
        success: function (response) {
          $('#d2d-results').html(response);
        }
      });
      if (history.pushState) {
          history.pushState(null, null, loc.pathname + '?' + fdata);
      }
  });
```

So how to get the categoryid from the URL and set it to ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for jQuery to parse URLs, you can use simple JS, like this:

```js
// Create a link tag from the URL
let link = document.createElement('a');
link.href = 'http://localhost/badar/category/produkterbaru/CT0007?brand=BR0006,BR0010';

// Take the last part of its path:
let categoryId = link.pathname.split('/').pop();

console.log(categoryId);
```

You seem to already have one such instance in your jQuery handler, so simply do this:

```
loc.pathname.split('/').pop()
```

Comment: Hi @Jeto, URL is from web address and I want to get it inside on change `$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function (e)` and the `link.href' is not manual input to variable but need to get it auto

Comment: @HiDayurieDave You seem to already have a link tag instance with `loc`. So did you try `loc.pathname.split('/').pop()`?

Comment: I got error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pathname' of undefined`

Comment: Ok got it now... wrong position set the `loc.pathname.split('/').pop()`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Jeto 's answer
Another approach would be 
If category id is always `CTXXXXX` then you could use regex in javascript

```js
var regex = /CT[0-9]*/

function getValue() {
  return document.getElementById("myinput").value;
}

function match() {
  alert(getValue().match(regex));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="myinput" value="http://localhost/badar/category/produkterbaru/CT0007?brand=BR0006,BR0010" />

<button id="matchBtn" onclick=match()>match</button>
```