# AJAX live search's data goes away after refreshing (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, livesearch, url-modification

I have an error related to *AJAX Live Search.*

When I search something from the Database, it searches the data and shows me the results of the data being searched, but when I refresh the page, the data goes away.

> I need for the URL to become `localhost/site/search.php?q=search_data` using the GET method in PHP when searching for something.

In AJAX, what I am currently doing is using GET and the URL as `url: "localhost/site/search.php?q=" + search_data`, and so I'm able to get the data eventually, but I want to modify the URL to `localhost/site/search.php?q=search_data` because otherwise whenever anyone wants to *bookmark* the specific search result page, it won't be able to be done and the data will go away.

Comment: So you want a live search to behave like a non-live search? If you want the search results to have a specific URL, you need to use something like [history's pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History) to manipulate the URL using JS while the user is searching. Then you also need to build a feature that checks the URL when the user enters the page so you can remake that search.

Comment: Here you can find your answer I hope this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url could be updated by using [histoy.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) function in js. The code should be like:

```
history.pushState(null, null, "?q=" + search_data);
```

You can use it to update state/url after ajax request and on refresh it will pass the same parameters as you require.

Comment: Hey @Lovepreet Singh, Thanks for replying! this works like a charm. Must be accepted :)

Comment: but after refreshing the URL remains same but the data vanishes how to resolve it?

Comment: You need to fetch records by using that information from url on page load.

Comment: pls can u help?

Comment: You can get query parameters from url and use those to get data on page load.

Comment: yeah i'm getting see this `$search_data = $_GET['q'];`

Comment: You also can get the with ajax and use this to hit same ajax request(as using to fetch results) on page load.