# Replace or remove query string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have url like this    `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/post?page=2&order=title`

I want to remove `?page={number}` or `&page={number}` query string

I don't have more knowledge about regular expression, is there an opinion to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add or update a query string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter)

Comment: I already read this. But Not according to my question

Comment: Explain why it's not the same as your question. Both questions are asking for how to update a query string.

Comment: The question referenced above was asked and answered in 2011. The answer does not reflect standard contemporary best practice, using `URLSearchParams` API. I have posted an answer appropriate to 2018 below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`URLSearchParams` is now the standard API for manipulating a URL query string.

**Working Example:**

**N.B.** *In the example below a string variable (`var windowLocationSearch`) is used as a stand-in for `window.location.search` which actually represents the query string at the end of the URL.*

```js
// Set window.location.search
var windowLocationSearch = 'page=2&order=title';

// Log window.location.search
console.log(windowLocationSearch);

// New URLSearchParams object
var searchParams = new URLSearchParams(windowLocationSearch);

// delete 'page' key from searchParams
searchParams.delete('page');

// Return query string from searchParams
windowLocationSearch = searchParams.toString();

// Log updated window.location.search
console.log(windowLocationSearch);
```

---

## Further Reading:

- `URLSearchParams` (MDN) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams
- `URLSearchParams.delete()` (MDN) - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/delete
- *Get Query String Parameters with JavaScript* by David Walsh - https://davidwalsh.name/query-string-javascript

Comment: the regex is still useful to know, esp in unit tests