# How to get first query string from url in jquery using Regex?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have url something like this

/test/test123/e/account/data/element?bUnit=17&name=cId&formName=TestForm&value=[self]

I just want to get first querystring and replace value of it so i tried

```
[\?&]([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```

Here is example url https://regex101.com/r/6qCllM/3

But getting all querystrings. I already have tried, just little mistake which want to fix. Don't want multiple lines of function.

How to get only one Query string and replace?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you're trying to select and replace? That whole substring is indeed *one* query string

Comment: put your inputs and expected out.

Comment: If you only want the first one, then why use `&`?  Change `[\?&]` to `[\?]` and it works in your refex101

Comment: If you want to find/replace a *specific* parameter (which sounds much more useful than just the first), then : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter  (and many other already answered questions that ask the same thing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the first `&`, this should work

```
[\?]([^=]+)\=([^&]+)
```