# Append value to URL search param

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a value to a search parameter in an URL but it's partly not working. For example I've this URL:

```
http://localhost.com/?color=Green&size=L
```

How can I add now a second value to color separated with a `,`?

This is how the URL must look after setting a second param:

```
http://localhost.com/?color=Green,Red&size=L
```

I've tried it with this here:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search + ',' + 'Red');
```

But the result is:

```
http://localhost.com/?color=Green,Red&size=L,Red
```

So how can I add a value comma separated to a search parameter in my URL?

Comment: The result you say you're getting doesn't look right. It should only have `,Red` at the end, not in the middle.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add or update a query string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter)

Comment: @HereticMonkey no, it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regular expression to match the `color=...` parameter.

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search.replace(/\bcolor=[^&]*/, '$&,Red'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the url, mutate it and build it up again:

```
  function parseURL(url) {
    const [domain, rest] = url.split("?");
    const args = {};
    for(const [k, v] of rest.split("&").map(pair => pair.split("=")))
      args[k] = v;
    return { domain, args };
 }

 const toURL = ({ url, args }) =>
    url + "?" + Object.entries(args).map(pair => pair.join("=")).join("&");

 const url = parseURL(window.location);
 url.args["color"] += ",Red";
 window.location = toURL(url);
```

That way you can easily modify all different parameters.