# JavaScript: pushState replace static value in search string

Tags: javascript, regex

I've this URL replace query:

```
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search.replace(/\bcolor=[^&]*/, '$&,Red'));
```

It works like it should but how can I change the first thing and replace `color` by a variable do make this dynamically like this way:

```
var value = 'color';
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search.replace(/\b  var_in_here  =[^&]*/, '$&,' + filter_value.attr('data-value') + ''));
```

**Update**

Because of the first answer from Jonas I've tried this here but it don't works:

```
var re = new RegExp('\b' + name + '=[^&]*');
window.history.pushState(null, null, window.location.search.replace(re, '$&,' + filter_value.attr('data-value') + ''));
```

Comment: This was a follow up question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53677336/append-value-to-url-search-param

Comment: Yes you are right :) good job! But this is not related to the question. The question was how I can add values. This question is about replacing static regex identifiers by variables. I'm just following the rules. For each topic a new question.

Comment: yes, this is definetly a new question but others answering should be able to see "the big picture"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could dynamically build up the regex:

```
 new Regex("\\b" + name + "=[^&]*")
```

Two `\` are needed to get this working.

Comment: Should I put this into the first part?

Comment: Can you take a look at my question? I've updated it. It don't works this way you told me or is there something wrong in my code again? Thanks!