# How to change URL parameter name using Jquery or plain JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am developing an app and we required some dynamic data so i wanted to change parameter name using Jquery.

This is my URL which has only 1 parameter:
`http://localhost:8888/games/result?subcat=lisconbyc&mode=16`

is it possible to change parameter name "mode" to "release"

so after changing the parameter name it should become
`http://localhost:8888/games/result?subcat=lisconbyc&release=16`

Please help.

Comment: Why on earth would you insist on using jQuery to do this? jQuery doesn't have any features that help with this kind of operation.

Comment: @Quentin plain JS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add or update a query string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with plain old JavaScript:

```js
console.log("http://localhost:8888/games/result?subcat=lisconbyc&mode=16".replace("&mode=","&release="))
```

So, in case there are multiple `<a>` elements on your page you can carry out this change with jQuery (if you wish) in the following way:

```
$("a").each(function(){this.href=this.href.replace("&mode=","&release=")});
```

Comment: works good, but i am trying something like this but doesn't work 
changeurl = (thisdata.replace("&mode=","&release=")); 
 $(this).find('.nopres').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).changeurl);