# How to replace query parameter only if it exists using string replace All regex

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, url, uri

I have following urls :

```
https://test1.com/path?query1=value1

and

https://test2.com/path
```

I am trying to add additional query param to all urls, so i am trying something like

```
url.replaceAll(/(.*)[?]?(.*)/g,"$1?newquery=newvalue&$2")
```

```js
let url = "https://test1.com/path?query1=value1"
console.log(url.replaceAll(/^(.*)[?]?(.*)$/g,"$1?newquery=newvalue&$2"))
url = "https://test1.com/path"
console.log(url.replaceAll(/^(.*)[?]?(.*)$/g,"$1?newquery=newvalue&$2"))
```

But it doesnt work as expected , could someone shed some light

Comment: In general, I would suggest using an explicit url parser to deal with urls, not regex. See e.g. [URL article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL). It seems easier to write/read, and you don't have to deal with (and can't accidentally miss) weird details about url formats.

Comment: @ASDFGerte THank you for the answer , but i am looking explicitly for regex match here just to understand how it behaves.  I am creating a commadn line utility that takes regex and converts url accordingly

Comment: As your regex starts with a greedy `.*`, and everything behind is optional, the first capture group can always consume everything. I also don't fully understand, why you use `replaceAll`, and a global modifier, when you always only ever operate on a single url, and do a single replace. For learning purposes, there are many regex visualization and testing tools, e.g. https://regex101.com/, https://regexr.com/, or for understanding the automata e.g. https://www.debuggex.com/

Comment: Have you checked [How can I add or update a query string parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999118/how-can-i-add-or-update-a-query-string-parameter)?

Comment: If you want a really simple solution, you can use `text.replace(/^([^?]*)(?:\?|$)/, '$1?newquery=newvalue&').replace(/&$/, '')`

Comment: @ASDFGerte the question is only part of the whole use case , the user can use any regex to replace anything in the url . say if they pass "test" then all occurance of the word test replaced. Here i want to show the regex to add query parameter to a url using regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First let's go through what your regex is doing, then we can fix it.
Your regex:

```
^ - the beginning of the string
(.*) - match any character 0 or more times - as many times as possible (greedy)
[?]? - match `?` 0 or 1 times
(.*) - match any character 0 or more times - as many times as possible (greedy)
$ - the end of the string
```

Really the main problem here is that the first capturing group captures as many times as possible, so that'll always match the entire url. We can make that non-greedy by using `.*?`, so we end up with `^(.*?)[?]?(.*)$`. However now we end up with the problem that the *last* capturing group captures the entire url - we could make this non-greedy but then it wouldn't match any characters at all. Instead, we should make sure that this group will only capture when `?` is present, so we can make `[?]?` non-optional, move it into the next capturing group, and make the last group optional, like this: `([?](.*))?`. Whilst we're at it, we might as well use `\?` instead of `[?]` and we end up with `^(.*?)(\?(.*))?$`. This works, as the `$` signifies that we want to capture right up to the end. With this we'd need to use `$3` instead of `$2` as `$2` now contains `?` as well when replacing, so we can use a non-capturing group to eliminate that problem.
So our final regex is `/(.*?)(?:\?(.*))?/g`.

Your final code will look like this:

```js
let url = "https://test1.com/path?query1=value1"
console.log(url.replaceAll(/^(.*?)(?:\?(.*))?$/g,"$1?newquery=newvalue&$2"))
url = "https://test1.com/path"
console.log(url.replaceAll(/^(.*?)(?:\?(.*))?$/g,"$1?newquery=newvalue&$2"))
```

Comment: Hi could you add a code snippet showing the example so that it will be more easy and interactive to understand

Comment: I've just edited my answer to give a code block and I also updated some parts as I slightly misread your question.

Comment: Thank you so much i added dont capture group to anser to avoid using $3 instead of $2