# Sorting the search result

Tags: python, django

I'm starting to learn Django and I ran into this problem: I can't add parameters to the link

Example:

Link before the change:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?brand=&search=
```

Link after the change:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?brand=&search=&sort=
```

What I get:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?sort=
```

How to implement it?

**views.py**

```
def filters(request):
    #search
    search_post = request.GET.get('search', '')
    if search_post:
        all = Product.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_post) & Q(content__icontains=search_post)).order_by()
    else:
        all = Product.objects.all()

    #sort by price
    sort_by = request.GET.get("sort", '')
    if sort_by == "l2h":
        all = Product.objects.all()
        all = all.extra(order_by = ['-price'])
    elif sort_by == "h2l":
        all = Product.objects.all().order_by('price')

    filters = IndexFilter(request.GET, queryset=all)

    context = {
        'filters': filters
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path

from .views import *
urlpatterns = [
    path('', filters, name='filters')
]
```

**index.html**

```
<form method="get" action="{% url 'filters' %}">
        {{ filters.form }}
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search"   placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        <a class="filter_by" href="?sort=l2h">Price:--low to high</a>
        <a class="filter_by" href="?sort=h2l">Price:-- high to low</a>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined 2 anchor tags in your code which change the URL completely and won't append new query parameters to your URL.

```html
<a class="filter_by" href="?sort=l2h">Price:--low to high</a>
<a class="filter_by" href="?sort=h2l">Price:-- high to low</a>
```

What you need to do is write some javascript code and use URLSearchParams to add this sort to existing url parameters.

Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41542008/7730705) to append parameters to url.

---

Or without javascript you can send those parameters to your template and change the href.

```py
def filters(request):
    #search
    search_post = request.GET.get('search', '')
    if search_post:
        all = Product.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=search_post) & Q(content__icontains=search_post)).order_by()
    else:
        all = Product.objects.all()

    #sort by price
    sort_by = request.GET.get("sort", '')
    if sort_by == "l2h":
        all = Product.objects.all()
        all = all.extra(order_by = ['-price'])
    elif sort_by == "h2l":
        all = Product.objects.all().order_by('price')

    filters = IndexFilter(request.GET, queryset=all)

    context = {
        'filters': filters,
        'search': search_post,
        'brand': request.GET.get('brand', '')
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

```html
<form method="get" action="{% url 'filters' %}">
        {{ filters.form }}
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search"   placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" name="search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        <a class="filter_by" href="?search={{ search }}&brand={{ brand }}&sort=l2h">Price:--low to high</a>
        <a class="filter_by" href="?search={{ search }}&brand={{ brand }}&sort=h2l">Price:-- high to low</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I don't know JavaScript yet. Are there any ways without JavaScript?

Comment: there is a way where you can send those query parameters that you receive in your view as context to template and use all of them in defining `href` for your anchor tags.

Comment: check the edited answer for using them without javascript