# How to handle values from two modals in the same page when page get refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, modal-dialog

I'm working on a rails form which contain two text-fields. Each text-fields are fed values through a look-up button which popups modal windows, which will trigger an `Ajax` call to fetch values. Then I select the values and set the values to the text-box fields.

The problem I'm facing is, when I set value in the second text-field, the page gets refreshed and first value in the text-box gets updated.

In my `controller` for form I'm capturing the `param` values from each modal and passing to the `template`. But when setting the second textfield value parent page gets refreshed and so the previous value get lost.

My question is, how to set two values before the form is submitted.

```
<td><%= f.text_field_tag(:node, :id, value: "#{@node_id}", class: "form-control", :readonly => true )%></td>
```

[image]

Comment: you can use local storage.

Comment: @pradeek why are you reloading the whole page?

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 When I select the value from the first modal then get back to the parent page the url get redirected right?

Comment: @pradeek no this shouldn't be the case. When you select anything from the modal the modal should get `refresh` everytime when you are trying to select/change value AND not the page.

Comment: @Ashraf.Shk786 Thanks, Here is my flow i click a lookup button the modal pops up and select the value then i pass values along with url redirection to the form page. After that the params values are captured by the form controller and set to input field in the form template.

Comment: Guys Thanks for the help , After a couple of thinking I come up with a simple solution to this, update me if I'm wrong. I chose to write a javascript event function to get the url and  params values and append to the textbox and just close the modal window and not doing url redirection.

Answer (score 0):

First, try to control parent page from getting reloaded. Since, if page gets reloaded definitely you will not be able to get the parameters entered by user in the previous state.

Else, you can also set `URL with parameters` when URL gets reloaded then take the parameters from the URL at the time of reloading to set the first text box. So, in that way both your text box values have values in the same state.

For your reference to append parameters to the URL:
[append to url and refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997450/append-to-url-and-refresh-page)