# Append an Input Field Value to a URL on a .cshtml Page

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I have a link to an SSRS report in my `.cshtml` page:

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
  <a href="http://xxx.xx.xx.x/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fCompany_Reporting%2fpayr0001&rs:Command=Render&StartDate=01/09/2017" target="_blank" >Timesheet Status Report</a>
</div>
```

I need to pass the value from my date control as a parameter as opposed to the hard-coded date above:

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id="datefrom">
</div>
```

I have tried appending an `onclick=myfunction()` to the url to add the date value, but can't get it to work.

```
function getStartDate() {
    return document.getElementById("datefrom").value; 
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you show the onclick function that you tried to add?

Comment: what is this `myfunction()` do? just posting html won't let us know what actually happen

Comment: <script>
    function getStartDate() {
        return document.getElementById("datefrom").value;
    }
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the href of the anchor tag on the date change attribute. Build the href on the go.

```
$('#datefrom').change(function(){
    $('#IdOfAnchorTag').attr('href','http://xxx.xx.xx.x/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fCompany_Reporting%2fpayr0001&rs:Command=Render&StartDate=' + $('#datefrom').val() );
});
```

Check the strings accordingly..

Comment: `IdOfAnchorTag` means `id` of the anchor tag.. Right? ok... But it has no `id` in OP code. Edit your answer about it ;) I mean... Explanations. (lol) You got what OP tries to do, I think.

Comment: Haha.. Common.. It would have an Id, class name.. something.. Considering the data he gave, I imagined it would be there.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're trying to do, as far as I can tell (duplicate question?):
[append to url and refresh page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5997450/append-to-url-and-refresh-page)

To get the date in the correct format, you'll have to do something like the following in the body of your function:
    `new Date($('input[type=date]').val()).toLocaleFormat();`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleFormat

Also, you're probably going to want to use 'onblur'/the blur event for the date input, or wire up your event handler function to a new button specifically for that purpose. This is because onclick/the click event will fire as soon as you click on the date input (which could open some sort of calendar widget, depending on the browser and browser version).

Answer (score 0):

Before you pass your date value to the url, You try converting your date to `dd-MM-yyyy` or `MM-dd-yyyy` instead of `dd/MM/YYYY`.
Because I think that when the url will misunderstand "/", so you should replace with "-".
Then if necessary, you can convert back to the old format.