# Defining a variable with jQuery from a different form

Tags: jquery, html

I want to get information from a previous form that was entered in a textBox. I am currently trying something like this:

```
var accNumber = $('#index.html').RegisterForm.cardNumberRegField.val();
```

and I have also tried

```
var tfscNum = document.RegisterForm.cardNumberRegField.value;
```

I know this is wrong. The HTML page I want to get the information from is `index.html`, and the form id is `RegisterForm`. The ID of the textBox in that form is `cardNumberRegField`

EDIT

this is the html code i am using for the textBox and the button on the index.html page

```
<form id="RegisterForm" method="post" data-ajax="false" id="registerCardForm" action="register.html"> 
        <input type="text" id="cardNumberRegField" type="tel"  name="cardNumber" class="required number register" minlength="16" maxlength="16"/> 
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" class="button" value="Register"/>
    </form>
```

Does anybody know the correct way to do this?

Comment: Is the form being posted from index.html to the second page? If not, you would have to pass the cardNumberField value through querystring / by posting it to the 2nd page.

Comment: You're trying to load this with `ajax`?

Comment: If you're trying to get a value from a textbox not on the current page, you'll need to persist that value in a cookie, query string, or some sort of server-side memory.

Comment: not the form is not being posted to the second page.... ya i am using ajax but only started learning it last week so not quite sure of how to use it fully yet

Comment: @FishBasketGordo how would i add this value to a query string?

Comment: @Hip Hip Array: Refer to this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

If the textbox is on the same page and you have the ID attribute set then simply 
`$('#cardNumberRegField').val();` will return the value.

Comment: no the textBox is not on the same page, it is on the previous page

Comment: Are you submitting the form on the previous page? If so then the values would be available via $_POST or $_GET depending on the method you use.

Comment: what do you mean by 'submitting' the form?

Comment: <form action="nextpage.php" method="post"><!-- other fields here--><input type="submit" value="submit" /></form> so when you press the submit button it goes to nextpage.php and in this case $_POST array will be filled with all the form fields you have.

Comment: oh right, ya i am submitting the form from the previous page, and using a mehtod="post"

Comment: Ok so you should be able to access via $_POST["cardNumberRegField"]. Do you use 'name' attribute for your form fields or just the 'id'?

Comment: i have added the code to my question of how the textBox and button are added, as you can see i use for the textBox i just use 'id' but for the button i use 'name'

Comment: ya i was trying it there and it wasnt working at all... i take it your suppose to put 'echo $_POST['cardNumber'];' in the .js page and not the .html page ya? ...... because it was trying to use it like var details = { .... tfscNumber : echo $_POST['cardNumber'], ...} to add it to an array

Comment: I just noticed you don't mention which language you are using to deal with the POST, the form action goes to register.html but are you using PHP?

Comment: you will need some sort of server side language to access the POST/GET data.