# Working with hashtags

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, tags, hashtag

Lets think that our URL look like

www.domain.com **#CourseID#LessonID**

What I'm trying to do is, when:

- `CourseDivButton` clicked if current url

  - Has no hashtag (www.domain.com) then just add `$(this).data("id")` as hashtag (www.domain.com **#CourseID**)
  - Contains only first hashtag - `CourseID` (www.domain.com **#CourseID**) then change it (www.domain.com **#NEWCourseID**)
  - Contains 2 hashtags - `CourseID` and `LessonID` (www.domain.com **#CourseID#LessonID**) then delete second and change first (www.domain.com **#NEWCourseID**)
- `LessonDivButton` clicked if current url

  - Contains only first hashtag - `CourseID` (www.domain.com **#CourseID**) then add second (www.domain.com **#CourseID#LessonID**)
  - Contains 2 hashtags - `CourseID` and `LessonID` (www.domain.com **#CourseID#LessonID**) then change second and leave first as it is (www.domain.com **#CourseID#NEWLessonID**)

My code now looks like below. Can't figure out how to achieve what I want.

```
CourseDivButton.click(function(){
    var id=$(this).data("id");
    LoadLessons(id);
    window.location.hash = id;
});

LessonDivButton.live("click", function(){
    var id=$(this).data("id");
    LoadQuestions(id);
    window.location.hash = id;
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: A hashtag is a means of highlighting a word for searching on twitter. The text after a `#` in a URI is a fragment identifier.

Comment: And [don't do that](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs)

Comment: @Quentin Sir, thanks for your advise. But, it's only for sharing link with commands. Even SO uses this technique.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing, but it seems far too complicated to be of any use to you or anyone else. Please describe what you're trying to do and I'm sure there's a much better way to do it.

Comment: @ThomasClayson Well, it's commands for ajax calls. `LoadLessons()` and `LoadQuestions()` are ajax call functions which sends id of course or lesson to backend, gets data, fills page. Without hashtags, user need to every time click to send ajax calls. But when you have url with hashtags, you can easily enter this url, share with others and get what you want without wasting time to clicks, page loads etc..

Comment: @epic_syntax — Stackoverflow does not use that technique. It uses the fragment identifier for its intended purpose - to link to a specific element on the page being linked to (not to determine what content to load via Ajax).

Comment: @Quentin I created this mechanism. I can't restructure whole project for only hashtag reason, so I need good solution to my question. Thanks for your advises, if you can please answer

Comment: @epic_syntax — Good solution: Follow the advice in the article I linked to and switch to the history API (which shouldn't require a restructuring of the whole project).

Comment: live is deprecated - please use .on or .delegate (for older versions)

Comment: @rlemon this works well. Please help me to solve main question

Comment: @epic_syntax please listen to me... and jQuery team when ***we*** say do not use live. this is a general tip. i'm trying to help you. live() is slow, does not chain, and has a few other *issues* with it. Please read the jQuery docs and you will see this.

Comment: @rlemon I'm listening to you, but IT'S NOT MAIN PROBLEM. Fast or slow: It works for now. My question is not related with live functions speed

Comment: which is why these are all comments and not **answers** - seriously. take it or leave it. I just gave some advice. no need to yell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using hashtags, couldn't you use query strings? I would suggest you add them like this:

www.domain.com?course=**CourseID**&lesson=**LessonID**

Using the javascript function below, you can grab the variables from the URL like so:

```
var courseID = urlParam('course');
var lessonID = urlParam('lesson');

function urlParam(name) {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the value of a parameter located within the url.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="name">The paramter to lookup.</param>
    /// <returns type="string">The value of the requested parameter, or undefined if the parameter is not present.</returns>
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regexS = "[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)";
    var regex = new RegExp(regexS);
    var results = regex.exec(window.location.href);
    if (results == null)
        return undefined;
    else
        return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

If you need to build a new URL with the query string added, [check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/487049/1654818).