# Adding an anchor to previous_post_links and next_posts_links in WordPress

Tags: php, javascript, html, wordpress, anchor

Struggling with this one...

In my WordPress theme I have a gallery at the top and blog posts below it. Each time I click the previous or next posts links it goes to the top which I don't want so I have created an anchor called #blog and placed in my html just below the gallery. How do add the anchor to the previous_post_links and next_posts_links to make it work? Is there a JavaScript solution for this?

Comment: You may need to use a filter to modify the link produced by these functions.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but here is how I dealt with adding an anchor to the previous and next posts link. You would add this into functions.php between the opening and closing  tags.

```
add_filter('get_pagenum_link', 'whatever_next_previous_anchor');

function whatever_next_previous_anchor($url) {
    return $url . '#blog';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the next and previous links have an ID or class that identifies them? Even if they don't you can still use Javascript or Jquery to append the #blog anchor to each link value. Check out this link [`Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript).

Comment: You should not use javascript in this case. Come on.

Comment: Ok, Javascript wouldn't be the recommended approach but if that is how you would like to do it then I have provided the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think that should do it, by using `get_previous_post()` instead :

```
     $prev_post = get_previous_post();
     if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
      <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>#blog">
        <?php echo $prev_post->post_title; ?></a>
     <?php endif; ?>
```