# Deal with query strings in JS, like http_build_query, etc

Tags: javascript, query-string, location-href

Here's what I have

```
if(condition1) {
     location.href = location.href+'/?site_type=normal';
}
else if(condition2) {
    location.href = location.href+'/?site_type=other';
}
```

Of course, if the location.href already has query vars on it, thats a problem, etc.

I need to

1. Find the vars from the query string
2. if site_type already exists, replace the value with either 'normal' or 'other'
3. rebuild the url with the new site_type

edit:
I found I needed to account for all kinds of URLs:

- domain.com
- domain.com/path/to/sth/
- domain.com/?site_type=normal
- domain.com?var=123&foo=987
- domain.com/path/?site_type=normal&var=123&foo=987

So, here's what I came up with, suggestions welcome:

```
var searchstring = window.location.search;
var url = window.location.href;

console.log('search: ' +  searchstring);
console.log( 'url: ' +  url);
// strip search from url
url = url.replace(searchstring,"");
console.log( 'url: ' +  url);
//strip site_type from search
searchstring = searchstring.replace("&site_type=normal","")
                        .replace("&site_type=other","")
                        .replace("?site_type=normal","")
                        .replace("?site_type=other","")
                        .replace("?","")
                        ;
console.log('search: ' +  searchstring);
if(searchstring != ''){searchstring = '&' + searchstring;}
var final = url + '?site_type=normal' + searchstring;
final = final.replace("&&","&");
console.log('final: ' +  final);
```

Comment: Related (consider duplicate keys): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly access the query string with `window.location.search`. You can convert it to an object using this regex trick found [here](http://stevenbenner.com/2010/03/javascript-regex-trick-parse-a-query-string-into-an-object/).

```
var queryString = {};
window.location.search.replace(/([^?=&]+)(=([^&]*))?/g, function($0, $1, $2, $3) {
  queryString[$1] = $3; }
);
```

Then set the `site_type` on `queryString` appropriately.

```
queryString["site_type"] = "normal";
```

And finally, convert it back into a string and set that as the `window.location.search`.

```
var searchString = "";
for ( q in queryString ) {
  searchString+="&" + q + "=" + queryString[q];
}
window.location.search = searchString;
```

Comment: Of course you could check `(window.location.search === "")` if you cared about the extra `&`.

Comment: I edited my answer with a solution that hopefully addresses everything now.

Comment: Great!  It looks like js automajically strips off the preceding '&' from the searchString before it appends it to the window.location?  Is there a way to get "window.location.search = searchString" into a variable so I can console.log it?  Thats just for me to understand it, it seems to be working with any kind of url i throw at it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do this:

```
//remove existing param and append new one..
var newHref = window.location.href.replace(window.location.search,"") + '?site_type=other';

//change href
window.location.href = newHref;
```

works only if you have one parameter that you want to replace, otherwise it would remove all parameters.

Answer (score 0):

for example if you have

yourpage.com/?site_type=normal

and you need only website not query vars you cans clear them

```
var novars= location.href.replace(window.location.search,"")
```

this case novars =  youroage.com

for just getting variables u can do this:

```
var site_type = window.location.search.replace("?site_type=","");
```

here i will get  site_type value whether its normal or other

this case your variable `site_type = "normal"`

for rebuilding url u can just add new site_type

```
location.href = novars+"?site_type=normal"
```

or

```
location.href = novars+"?site_type=other"
```