# JS/JQuery: add a parameter to path with unknown number of parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a JS script that relies on an AJAX call which adds a parameter to an html request. I'm running into two issues.

1. I can't figure out a simple way to get the pathname including parameters. In straight JS, `location.pathname` only returns the current path without the parameters. With JQuery, `$(document).href` returns the whole URL, but including stuff I don't want such as scheme, domain, etc. Is there a nice, simple, easy method that returns just the path including parameters?
2. Once I have the path, I haven't yet figured out a good way of adding a parameter, given that the path may already include zero or more parameters. Luckily I don't need to update a key that already exists, just add a new one. I've found some similar questions on SO already, for instance: [Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript), but is there a way to do this without writing my own URL parser or other boilerplate code?

Comment: So you already have a bunch of solutions from that other question. So why would you need to write your own parser? They are already written for you in those answers. They also show how to get the parameters from the `location`. Maybe you should just take some time and work with the code you found.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)

Comment: And if you're using jQuery, `$(document).href` doesn't return the whole `href`. It returns `undefined`.

Comment: Well geez, thanks for the love. Would you like me to defend why this isn't a duplicate? For one thing, I'm asking if there are any jquery or javascript methods of doing what I want; the other question only asked about js. Also, I have another related issue that hasn't been addressed that I posted. Finally, maybe some methods of doing what I want have emerged since the other question was asked. It doesn't hurt for me to just ask, right? Or maybe it does.

Comment: Also, sorry about the bad method. I was in a rush as I left for work, you're right that $(document).href isn't valid. Once I'm home again, I'll have to look at what I did call on $(document) to get the whole URL. It would still be nice to have a way to get only the path with the parameters as well.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing new in browsers to handle this. If/when there are, I'm certain you'll see new answers pop up on those old questions. WRT jQuery, best place to look is its http://api.jquery.com/ where they have a decent search tool. Aside from that, there are many pre-written solutions just waiting for you, in addition the ones you found. Google is very helpful in that regard. Oh, and I love you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my own question.

It turned out to be a lot easier than any other solution I found so far.

In JS, `location.search` returns the query parameter string of the URI. So I can simply check if it exists and add `&foo=bar` to the end of the URI if it does, `?foo=bar` if it doesn't. No parsing necessary.

Incidentally, this also answers my other question: `location.pathname+location.search` returns the path including the query parameters.

This solution won't work for all cases, though it works for mine. Some issues that might arise: if you want to modify an existing parameter, additional parsing is necessary. Or if your parameters contain characters such as `?` or `&`, additional escaping is necessary. A more complete solution is here: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20020107.asp

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to get the pathname including parameters only is get complete url first by using location.href like var path= window.location.href, then split this url like ( var pathQyeryPramater = path.split("/")[3] ) according to your requirement. This pathQyeryPramater will return whole path with query parameteres only and then follow up above answer.