# Javascript/JQuery: set a request attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, httprequest

With `var test = "${attributename}";` is possible to get the request attribute "attributename" from javascript/jquery.

Is there a way to set a request attribute in a similar way in javascript/jquery?

Comment: @Stano: I'm using struts 1.3. I need to set a form property according to an ajax call response. I succeed in doing it: in the success callback I replace a div with another one in the response (this div contains the form property field properly setted). But I have some side effects, so I wanted to resolve in another way, for example by setting a request attribute in the success callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set a request attribute in a similar way in javascript/jquery
```

NO.

Request and response available on server side ...you cannot access in javascript.

```
var test = "${attributename}";
```

resolves on compile time  at server side.

You might misunderstand that jsp and `javascript` existed on same `document`.Yes but JSP part compiles on server side itself comes to `client`.

I did'nt get your intention here, that while sending `request`,set `parameter` and do a `request`.No matter weather it is Ajax,Html form ..etc

Comment: I'm using struts 1.3. I need to set a form property according to an ajax call response. I succeed in doing it: in the success callback I replace a div with another one in the response (this div contains the form property field properly setted). But I have some side effects, so I wanted to resolve in another way, for example by setting a request attribute in the success callback

Comment: take a hidden field and use it

Answer (score 0):

Your question wasn't phrased too clearly, but if you are looking to get/set the request parameters of the url... take a look at the following posts:

Get a request parameter from the current url:
[How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values)

And set a request parameter:
[Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)