# Reload an image with setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, settimeout

when I load a image and loading fails, I try to reload after a delay using `setTimeout`, as below:

```
$('img').error(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src') + '?' + Math.random());
    }, 3000);
});
```

But this solution doesn't reload the image as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `this` changes to `window` in your inner function scope. Save a reference to the jQuery wrapper of your `image` when the outer function is triggered.

```
$('img').error(function() {
    var $img = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $img.attr('src', $img.attr('src') + '?' + Math.random());
    }, 3000);
});
```

---

**Edit:**
As @epascarello pointed out, you're assuming there aren't any existing query params already on the image when you append `?randomNum`. If you know that will always be the case, that's fine, although the param really should be `?key=randomNum`. If it's possible that there are existing params, you'll have to do something similar to the below. (*But do you really need to append a random number to the URL?*).

```
function updatedSrc(oldSrc) {
    var delim = (oldSrc.indexOf('?') != -1) ? '&' : '?';
    return oldSrc + delim + "rand=" + Math.random();
}
```

And when you update the `src` you would do `$img.attr('src', updatedSrc($img.attr('src')))`.

Comment: @epascarello Ah good point, I didn't catch that, that could also be an issue

Comment: Of course, this still isn't ideal for appending query params. You can see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript) for a more full-featured solution. This should be good enough for this scenario.

Answer (score 3):

`this` is no longer referring to $("img") you need to assign a varialbe as a placeholder for `this`

```
$('img').error(function(){
    var $self = $(this);
    setTimeout(function(){
    $self.attr('src', $self.attr('src')+'?'+Math.random());
    }, 3000);
});
```

Comment: This always mystified me.  Why is it that `$(this)` refers to the image when you do the variable assignment, but to something else when you run the `.attr()` method?

Comment: @Paul It doesn't refer to the image in either case; `this` would be the same in both those cases, because the scope hasn't changed there.

Comment: querystring is wrong.... going to be ...gif?312321?234234234?234234234?234234234?23423423423?234234234?@3423234 after a few iterations.

Comment: the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called.  If the function doesn't explicitly assign the value of `this` (and you're not in strict mode), then `this` will refer to the global object.  If you call a function on an object, `this` will then refer to the object that the function was called on.  The value of `this` changes when we call the anonymous function inside of `setTimeout()`.

Comment: What's happening here, is we are calling a function on each `img` node via jQuery.  Since a method is being called on an object, `this` refers to the object.  If we call a new function, the value of `this` changes depending on how it was called.  In this case, since we don't explicitly define `this`, it would be the global object.  I hope that helps clarify @PaulProgrammer