# Why can't I add parameters to the window.location?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Using Javascript, I'm trying to reload my page and add a parameter before doing so.  I've added the alerts to debug why the parameter is not getting passed to the server:

```
    alert('before: ' + window.location.href);
    window.location.href = window.location.href + "?advanced_expand=true";
    alert('after: ' + window.location.href);
    window.location.reload();
```

What has me perplexed is that the first alert is:

> before: http://localhost:3000/orgconf/quick_org_benefit/edit/784

and the second is:

> after: http://localhost:3000/orgconf/quick_org_benefit/edit/784

*without* the parameter added...what gives?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing the `window.location.reload()` afterwards is pointless because setting `window.location.href` changes the page.
Likewise, `window.location.href` doesn't actually change until the page changes. That's why you aren't seeing the URL change.

If the page is reloading and it *still* hasn't changed, make sure your URL rewriting isn't removing GET parameters that come after a `?`.

Comment: In fact `window.location.reload()` reloads the *current* page and therefore discards changes to `window.location.href`.

Comment: @Juhana Ah, I see, so how can I achieve a reload with the added parameter then?  I'm assuming it can be done?

Comment: @MarkKadlec Simply don't call `window.location.reload()` after setting `window.location.href`.

Comment: @MikeC, I see, I was reverting by actually calling the reload, doh!