# url encode & decode parameter and read parameter

Tags: java, url-encoding

i success encode & decode the url parameter but how can i get the parameter after decode?? the reason i encode all query strings into a parameter just to prevent user change the parameter on the address bar.

### For example

Page A

```
  function fnlink()
    {
        param1 = encodeURIComponent("INSCODE=91&NAME=LEE&EMAIL=abc");
    url = "/home/test/test2.jsp?"+param1;

    location.href= url; 
    }
```

Page B

url : http://localhost:9080/home/test/test2.jsp?INSCODE%3D91%26NAME%3DLEE%26EMAIL%3Dabc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse a URI String into Name-Value Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13592236/parse-a-uri-string-into-name-value-collection shows you how to use `URL.getQuery` to extract the query part and then use `String.split` to get the individual parts into a map. Then use the map's methods to check & get values for specific parameters.

Comment: The method `getParameter` of request object returns the parameter you're looking already decoded. Not clear what's your problem.

Comment: @freedev `getParameter` is a method that the OP wished existed.

Comment: Just so you are aware.. You are appending the QueryString parameters wrong. It should be: `request.getRequestURL() + "?" + request.getQueryString()`.. Note the question mark.

Comment: ok simple.. what i want is how to get parameter inscode, name, email.. java 7 not 8 ..

Answer (score 2):

You should not encode the entire parameters string `"INSCODE=91&NAME=LEE&EMAIL=abc"` with [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

Each parameter should be encoded separately. 
Use a Javascript function [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript/14469938#14469938) to add your parameters at query string:

```
/**
* Add a URL parameter 
* @param {url}   string  url 
* @param {param} string  the key to set
* @param {value} string  value 
*/
var addParam = function(url, param, value) {
   param = encodeURIComponent(param);
   var a = document.createElement('a');
   param += (value ? "=" + encodeURIComponent(value) : ""); 
   a.href = url;
   a.search += (a.search ? "&" : "") + param;
   return a.href;
}
```

Comment: i tried this method, my parameter did not encode .. when redirect my parameter still show exact parameter ..