# On select change redirect to url jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to redirect to url when a select is changed and add option text in url query parameter, I have tried this but it seems not working:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            var url = window.location.href;
            $("#select-opt").change(function() {
                var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
                url = option.data("url");
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-opt" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="test-select1.html">Value 1</option>
        <option value="test-select2.html">Value 2</option>
        <option value="test-select3.html">Value 3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: I don't think it's helping that you're mixing inline script (in the `onchange`) and the jQuery script. Try doing everything everything in the jQuery.  Also, setting the `window.location.href` into a variable and then updating the variable does **not** update the `window.location.href`

Comment: You need to take the value of your selected option for your redirect, such as "option.val()" or "$(this).find('option:selected').val()". This you need to use with "window.location.href = " instead setting the url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `window.location.href` to a variable, and then updating the variable will **not** set `window.location.href`

I've moved your `onchange` code into the jquery and fixed the error.

I've also added the code to add the text from the option to the query string.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#select-opt").change(function() {
    var $option = $(this).find(':selected');
    var url = $option.val();
    if (url != "") {
      url += "?text=" + encodeURIComponent($option.text());
      // Show URL rather than redirect
      $("#output").text(url);
      //window.location.href = url;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-opt">
  <option value="">Select one</option>
  <option value="test-select1.html">Value 1</option>
  <option value="test-select2.html">Value 2</option>
  <option value="test-select3.html">Value 3</option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, exactly this is working perfectly fine as per my requirement, I just checked, I think I will have to encode url so doesn't add `%20` in text

Comment: If you don't want `%20` then I suggest you use `+` instead, as having spaces in the URL (even in the query string) is not a good idea

Comment: So you mean adding `+` within option text?

Comment: No, add `.replace("%20", "+")` to the result of `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Thanks very much!

Comment: You're welcome @Sanjeev - good luck with the rest of your project

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#select-opt").change(function() {
        window.location.href = $(this).val();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-opt" onchange="this.options[this.selectedIndex].value && (window.location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
        <option value="test-select1.html">Value 1</option>
        <option value="test-select2.html">Value 2</option>
        <option value="test-select3.html">Value 3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but on select change I also wanted to send `Value 1` in url query parameter or whichever is selected

Comment: For adding query parameter in URL you can refer this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript). @SanjeevKumar

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```js
$('#select-opt').on('change', function() {
    var selectedOption = $(this).val(); //or use this: $(this).find(':selected').val();
    var parameter = '?text=';
    var parameterValue = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    var url = selectedOption+parameter+parameterValue;
    if(selectedOption != "") {
        alert(url);
        //window.location.href=''+url;
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-opt">
    <option value="">Select value</option>
    <option value="test-select1.html">Value 1</option>
    <option value="test-select2.html">Value 2</option>
    <option value="test-select3.html">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

You were actually really close. What you need is to store the value of your select as your url path, but leave the `window.location.href` as its own function, and simply put the url variable at the end of it.

right now I am just alerting the path for testing / visual purposes in this example. If you remove the alert and out-comment the line below, you would get your desired redirect instead.

Alternatively, you can use

`$(this).find(':selected').val()`

instead of

`$(this).val()`

for your selected option value. Depends what version of jQuery you run with I believe.