# Add params to url with javascript

Tags: javascript

hello I want to add some params to a url

```
let params = {doors: 4, color: red}
let request = new Request('/api/cars')
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => request.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
```

but I´m getting the Cannot read property 'append' of undefined error

it works if I do

```
var url = new URL('https://example.com/api/cars');
Object.keys(params).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
let request = new Request(url)
```

but since I´m not using **URL** only relative urls I´m wondering if is not possible to append params to **Request**

Comment: check it out this issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript i hope this can help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a parameter to the URL with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) object and append it to the URL string. Here is an example:

```js
const params = {
  doors: 4,
  color: 'red'
};
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams();
Object.entries(params).forEach(([key, value]) => searchParams.append(key, value));

const request = new Request(`/api/cars?${searchParams.toString()}`);
console.log(request.url);
```

Comment: that´s exactly what I stopped doing because I don´t know the domain. yeah I know is dumb

Comment: You can get it using `localtion.hostname`.

Comment: @handsome I've edited my answer to include an example using `URLSearchParams`. You can use a relative URL with this solution.

Comment: Now you always have a ugly question mark at the end of the route if params is empty. Is there it bettery way to add the params without something like `searchParams.size ? '?' + searchParams.toString() : ''`?

Comment: @YannickSchröder Yes, you can create a `URL` object, modify its `searchParams` and then use `\`/api/cars${url.search}\``, [here is an example](https://jsbin.com/xarixoqogo/edit?js,console)

Comment: @Titus That only works for absolute urls but not for relative urls.

Comment: @YannickSchröder If you take a look at the example, it is setup to work just like the one in my answer. The only thing from the `URL` object that is used in the end result is its `search` property. (this is the example that I'm talking about: https://jsbin.com/xarixoqogo/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

The [`Request()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/Request) constructor creates a new Request object. So you should use it asynchronously with `fetch`:

```
let params = {doors: 4, color: red};
let request = new Request('/api/cars');

fetch(request).then(function(response) {
  Object.keys(params).forEach(key => response.searchParams.append(key, params[key]))
})
```