# Primefaces get value from input text without bean binding

Tags: javascript, jsf

I have simple button and input text:

```
<p:button id="someBtnID" value="Join" />
<p:inputText id="someID" placeholder="ID" />
```

I want on button click get value from input text, concat it and do redirect.
For example: I have link `domain.com/folder/action=`

```
input text value = 11025
```

I need concat value from input text here and do redirect to `domain.com/folder/action=11025`

Can I do it without binding with any bean in JSF but on frontend?

Comment: This is easier to figure out yourself when you keep in mind that JSF is merely a HTML code generator. If not, then you'll probably need to take a step back and learn basic HTML first. I.e. just figure out how exactly you would do this in plain vanilla HTML. And then simply rewrite JSF code accordingly that it produces the desired HTML output.

Comment: Also doing this frontend is a task for javascript and jsf can't help you with that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript) question might help you with that