# How to send form data through get request in fetch api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, fetch-api

I was having an API where I am calling a get request to send to query parameters through form data but I am getting get request doesn't take form data. How to do it

[image]

`http://ihub-fastapi-solubility.herokuapp.com/predict?solute=CC(C)(C)Br&solvent=CC(C)(C)O` this is the URL and solute and solvent are the query parameters.

```js
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // <-- prevent the default form action

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.set("solute", solutestate); // <-- local component state
    formData.set("solvent", solventstate); // <-- local component state
    console.log({ formData });

    fetch("http://ihub-fastapi-solubility.herokuapp.com/predict", {
      method: "get",
      body: formData,
    }).catch((err) => {
      setError(err.error);
      console.log(err);
    });
```

When I tried with `post` I got this error
[image]

Comment: You can't send body with GET request, only with POST. Change the API so that it accepts and processes POST requests

Comment: @ComixRu I don't think OP _wants_ to send a POST request at all, they just want to capture their `FormData` params as query parameters

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61829691

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) isn't the best choice here as that is primarily used in constructing `multipart/form-data` request payloads for use in `POST`, `PUT` and `PATCH` requests.

Use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) instead to easily construct query parameters and serialise it into the URL...

```js
const fetch = function fakeFetch(url, init) {
  console.log(init.method, url)
}

const solutestate = "CC(C)(C)Br"
const solventstate = "CC(C)(C)O"

const params = new URLSearchParams({
  solute: solutestate,
  solvent: solventstate
})

fetch(`http://ihub-fastapi-solubility.herokuapp.com/predict?${params}`, {
  method: "GET"
})
```

Using `URLSearchParams` has the added benefit of correctly [URL encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) your data.

Comment: Also see [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for more about the `${}`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@phil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71027713): If you've got a form already, you can use `FormData` to initialize the `URLSearchParams`.

For example, if you've got a form like this

```html
<form method="get" action="" id="form">
...
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

you can submit it as follows

```js
const form = document.getElementById("form");
form.addEventListener("submit", submitForm);

function submitForm(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const url = form.action + "?" + new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form));
  fetch(url)...
}
```