# Use Shopify API with Google Sheet GET request Orders

Tags: google-apps-script, shopify

```
function myfunction() {
  var url = "https://storename.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/orders.json";
  var payloaddata =  "orders_number"
  
  var payload = JSON.stringify(payloaddata);
  var username = "<user>";
  var password = "<pass>";

  var response = UrlFetchApp.getRequest(url,{
    method: "GET",
    payload: payload,
    contentType: "application/json",
    headers: { "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password) }
  });

  Logger.log(response);
  var json = response.getContentText();
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  Logger.log(data);
}
```

> any help with Shopify API to google sheet app script? I got an error that says `no function getContentText();`. Any recommendation ?

Comment: What does the `Logger.log(response)` has? Have you checked the documentation on [getRequest()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl)?

Answer (score 1):

For why it is not working, because there is no such function on the returned object. [getRequest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#getrequesturl,-params) documentation states that

> Returns the request that is made if the operation were invoked. This
> method does not actually issue the request.

[getContentText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getcontent) is a method of [HTTP Response](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response) that is returned by fetch.

Moreover, Payload can only be sent for POST requests. Fixing above, your code will be

```
function myfunction() {
    var url = "https://storename.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-10/orders.json";
    var payloaddata = "orders_number"


    var payload = JSON.stringify(payloaddata);
    var username = "<user>";
    var password = "<pass>";

    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
   //     payload: payload,
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)
        }
    });


    Logger.log(response);
    var json = response.getContentText();
    var data = JSON.parse(json);
    Logger.log(data);
}
```

For query params with GET requests, send them via [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486896/adding-a-parameter-to-the-url-with-javascript).