# I need to connect Google Sheets to my Shopify store fo orders info

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, shopify-api

I need to create a Google Sheet table which can dinamically update my shopify store orders info organized in columns

Hello!
I asked Chat GPT how could I connect a Google Sheet to Shopify in order to get a table which contains all the orders info (like date, order umber, billing & shipping country ecc.). The script it generated is this one:

```
function getShopifyOrders() {
  var shopifyApiKey = 'API_KEY';
  var shopifyPassword = 'PASSWORD';
  var shopifyStore = 'STORENAME.myshopify.com';

  var url = 'https://' + shopifyStore + '/admin/api/2023-07/orders.json';
  var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(shopifyApiKey + ":" + shopifyPassword)
  };

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {"headers": headers});
  var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());

  // Ora puoi elaborare i dati e inserirli nella tua tabella Google Sheets.
}
```

I inserted the login info, activated a token on the private app I created on my shopify backend and run the script on Google AppScript. It has an error which is:

> Exception: Request failed for https://urbanstaroma.myshopify.com returned code 401. Truncated server response: {"errors":"[API] Invalid API key or access token (unrecognized login or wrong password)"} (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
> getShopifyOrders  @ Codice.gs:11

Can you tell me if there is any error in this script, or maybe is not right at all?

Thanks! :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use Shopify API with Google Sheet GET request Orders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65138178/use-shopify-api-with-google-sheet-get-request-orders)