# Print a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div that contains: text , backround color, image

and i want to print only this div.

I'm kind of clueless so any help could help

thanks.

Comment: Have you done any research? And to print? What do you mean? Where? Post some code please...

Comment: Possibly this will help you a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7608110/how-to-print-a-dynamic-div-html-element-using-jquery

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12181825/603003 I have already posted an answer there!

Comment: not a difficult topic to research with a little bit of search effort

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to define a print stylesheet. You do this in the following manner:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your url" type="text/css" media="print" />
```

In that sheet you specify how to display your website for the printed page. So what you can do is set every element to `display:none` except for the div you wish to print.

You can do this easily with the following selectors:

```
* {
    display: none;
}

#printDiv {
    display: block;
}
```

and simply apply the id `printDiv` to the div you wish to print.

Comment: is it possible to take the div and make it a jpeg? or a gif?

Comment: Why would you do that? Are you saying is it possible to only print an image (thus an img tag), or do you actually want to serialize your div into an image format?

Comment: i want to serialize your div into an image format

Comment: If you're printing it anyway why would it need to be an image...

Comment: Anything is possible with computers, but the practical answer is a definitive no. I am sure that with a bit of googling however you can find a way to achieve what you wish to achieve with CSS, JS and HTML. Andy does pose a good question.

Comment: for those who are copying and pasting, the link tag has some typo's in it!

Comment: What would those be? I'll correct if you point them out.

Answer (score 3):

What have u tried?

Maybe this helps:

You require to create new style sheet print.css and set `CSS media=print`

for example :

```
<style media="screen">
  .noPrint{ display: block; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>

<style media="print">
  .noPrint{ display: none; }
  .yesPrint{ display: block !important; }
</style>
```

Giv the specific div the `.yesPrint` class and all other the `.noPrint`.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently used this JQuery plugin to do something similar

http://projects.erikzaadi.com/jQueryPlugins/jQuery.printElement/

Comment: Guys finding this at 2015 or newer, the printElement uses $.browser which is removed from jquery since v1.9 and won't work.